# Alter CSS class attributes with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a CSS class defined, call it:

```
<style type="text/css">
.Foo { position: fixed; left: 50px; top: 50px; }
</style>
```

where I position an element on the screen absolutely.  Throughout my web page's execution, I create and delete many elements and give them class `Foo`.  When I resize the browser, I want to change the `left` and `top` values on the `Foo` class so the position of *all* `Foo` elements is changed as a result of a calculation.

I don't want to simply change stylesheets, I want to calculate a value and make all current and future `Foo` elements have that new calculated `left` and `top` value.

This site has an example, but the code's quite complex.
http://www.shawnolson.net/a/503/altering-css-class-attributes-with-javascript.html

Is there a good, clean way to basically programmatically alter what `Foo` is defined as?

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding your comment on my solution, you can remove the last added style tag when adding a new one, or simply edit the contents of the same style tag everytime.

Comment: I updated my answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
<script>
var style;
function changeFoo(left, top) {
    if(typeof style == 'undefined') {
        var append = true;
        style = document.createElement('style');
    } else {
        while (style.hasChildNodes()) {
            style.removeChild(style.firstChild);
        }
    }
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var rules = document.createTextNode(
        '.Foo { left: ' + left + 'px; top: ' + top + 'px; }'
    );

    style.type = 'text/css';
    if(style.styleSheet) {
        style.styleSheet.cssText = rules.nodeValue;
    } else {
        style.appendChild(rules);
    }
    if(append === true) head.appendChild(style);
}
</script>
```

This code was modified from an answer provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript/524717) which is very similar to what you asked. Whenever you need to change the position of all .Foo elements, you can just call changeFoo(newLeftValue, newTopValue); - the first time around it will create the `<style>` element and add it to the `<head`> of the document. Subsequent calls will just empty the `<style>` element that was already added and add the new rule.

Comment: I think this will work, but the drawback is if Foo changes frequently, say, 100 times - there'll be 100 definitions for Foo on the page (with the cascading effect causing the latest one to take effect).  I don't see that being good for performance.