# CSS / Javascript Show / Hide DIV using a CSS class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've googled around and found many scripts for hiding and showing DIV contents, as a toggle on button click.

But they are work using ID's.

I would like to do the same thing BUT I want to use a class instead of an id so that if I want to have 20 DIV's that toggle ... Hide / Show I don't have to add extra code.

Here is some code:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "show";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
} 
</script>

<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">show</a> <== click Here
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none"><h1>peek-a-boo</h1></div>
```

Can anyone help with this please?

Thanks

Comment: what code do you have so far?

Comment: It's the same as with an id except an id is designated by "#" and a class is designated by a "."

Comment: Do you want ALL tags to toggle simultaneously? Or each individually with a generic class to group them under?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is jquery an option?  Hopefully so, because this does what you want:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```
$(".class").toggle();
or
$(".class").show();  $(".class").hide();
```

Answer (score 4):

Most of the jQuery answers should be pretty easy, but seeing as your example is in regular JS, here's how to do it in JS.

Potential downside: browsers that don't support getElementsByTagName. I tested IE7 and it works, but I'm not sure about lower.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

var toggle = function() {    
    for (var i = 0, l = divs.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (divs[i].getAttribute('class') == 'problem') 
            if (divs[i].style.display == 'none') divs[i].style.display = '';
            else divs[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}

document.getElementById('Toggle').onclick = toggle;
```

**Try it out**: http://jsfiddle.net/robert/PkHYf/

Answer (score 4):

As others have said several times, this is easy in jQuery using a jquery selector and the .hide method. However, since you are asking in a general sense and it is a good idea to know how to do it without a framework, that isn't a complete answer.

Here are your options:

1. JQuery Method.  Just use jQuery selectors and the .hide() method.

   $(".CLASSNAME").hide()
2. Vanilla JS: Dynamic CSS.  One approach is to dynamically append stylesheets to the document head -- you can [Alter CSS class attributes with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580216/alter-css-class-attributes-with-javascript)
3. Vanilla JS: Modify CSS directly:

   ```
       var ss = document.styleSheets;
       for (var i=0; i<ss.length; i++) {
           var rules = ss[i].cssRules || ss[i].rules;

           for (var j=0; j<rules.length; j++) {
               if (rules[j].selectorText === ".classname") {
                   rules[j].style.visibility = "none";
               }
           }
       }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this just be

```
$('.classname').hide();
```

Or group all the elements you want to hide within a container div, and then hide that div.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery:

```
$(".classname").hide();
```

where `classname` is the name of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery Selectors, you can find an ID by:

```
$("#id")
```

Changing that to select classes is trivial:

```
$(".className")
```

Without using jQuery its a little more non-trivial, but you can check this SO question for some help:

[How to getElementByClass instead of GetElementById with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933602/how-to-getelementbyclass-instead-of-getelementbyid-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `$(".className").hide();`

The `$(".somthing")` do the same as `$("#somthing")`, except it's for a class instead of an ID.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great solution to this for Vanilla JS:

https://attacomsian.com/blog/javascript-hide-show-elements-using-css-class

Add/remove a `.hidden` css class.