# Hide div by class id

Tags: javascript, html, visibility

If I have 
    `<div id="ad1" class="ad">`
and
    `<div id="ad2" class="ad">`
how can I hide both by hiding all divs with class ad

I tried 
    `document.getElementsByClassName(ad).style.visibility="hidden";`
but only this works
    `function hidestuff(boxid){
   document.getElementById(boxid).style.visibility="hidden";
}`

Comment: getElementsByClassName('ad')

Comment: Hint: `getElementsByClassName` returns more than one element.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('ad').style.display="none";

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS / Javascript Show / Hide DIV using a CSS class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836710/css-javascript-show-hide-div-using-a-css-class)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Matt Ball's clue left, you need to iterate through the results of your getElementsByClassName result.

Try something along the lines of:

```
    var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("ad");

    for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++)
    {
    divsToHide[i].style.visibility="hidden";
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted Worked Fantastically

Answer (score 2):

use jquery [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Kqyk/)

```
$('.ad').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.divClassName').hide();
```

This will solve your problem.

In your case it will be like below.
    $('.ad').hide();
This will hide all the elements with class name 'ad'.

Answer (score 0):

To make the content visible which is inside iframe - pls try below:

```
var frame = document.getElementById("chatFeed"); 
var msg2 =frame.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName("publisherWrapper");
for (i = 0; i < msg2.length; i++) {
msg2[i].style.visibility="visible";
}
```