# Dynamically loading css stylesheet doesn't work on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I dynamically load a css stylesheet (with a little help from jQuery) like this:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
$(document.createElement('link'))
    .attr({ type: 'text/css', href: '../../mz/mz.css', rel: 'stylesheet' })
    .appendTo(head);
```

This works fine in Firefox and Google Chrome, but *not* in IE.

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Once IE has processed all the styles loaded with the page, the only reliable way to add another stylesheet is with `document.createStyleSheet(url)`

See the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531194%28VS.85%29.aspx) on createStyleSheet for a few more details.

```
url = 'style.css';
if (document.createStyleSheet)
{
    document.createStyleSheet(url);
}
else
{
    $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + url + '" />').appendTo('head'); 
}
```

Comment: Documentation for document.createStyleSheet:
http://www.ssicom.org/js/x276572.htm
(the MSDN article fails with a 503 error...). Note that the returned object is a DispHtmlStyleSheet object, not a LINK element. To get the link tag from this object, you need to access document.createStyleSheet('...').owningElement

Comment: I believe dynamically creating a new style tag  `<style>your style here</style>` and adding it into <head> also works in IE.

Comment: Update 09/2013: createStyleSheet method is no longer supported. For more information, visit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: My solution below disagrees,

Comment: I tried @ekerner's solution below, but this is the only solution that worked in IE9 (emulated mode).

Comment: see browser support  http://help.dottoro.com/ljpxthtl.php and below can see a cross-browser solution

Answer (score 40):

You need to set the href attr last and only after the link elem is appended to the head:

```
$('<link>')
  .appendTo('head')
  .attr({type : 'text/css', rel : 'stylesheet'})
  .attr('href', '/css/your_css_file.css');
```

**Update**

Nowadays the only purpose of IE and Edge is to download Chrome, so I recommend NOT bloating your code with custom support for IE or Edge and rather just ignoring their existence.

Comment: This is an important Internet Explorer quirk to note (even as recently as IE 8), and was absolutely critical to a project I was working on.  Thanks for noting it here.  When will folks stop using IE?

Comment: I like this better than the IE-only 'document.createStyleSheet' method.

Comment: This did work for me on an IE9 in IE8 compatibility mode but failed on a pure/real IE8. On a real IE8 only the 'document.createStyleSheet' method was reliable for me. Just to let others know who experience the same issue.

Comment: @Kosi2801 - Strange. It works nicely on my pure/real IE8 in IE8 standart mode.

Comment: @Chris Moschini : Not much ever did work in IE6. But Iv had this running in IE6, not that it matters any more.

Comment: For this to work on my actual IE8 win7 VM from modern.ie, I had to put quotes the attribute names : 'type' and 'rel'...

Comment: @Pierre are you sure about that Pierre? {type : 'text/css', rel : 'stylesheet'} is just a Javascript object declaration and you should not need to quote the keys.

Comment: Tested this in IE9 and it solved a stylesheet injection issue I was having! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Just in case this helps, I was getting a blank white screen whenever I appeneded a stylesheet to the DOM in IE8. Using this fixed my bug. THANK YOU!

Comment: What about inline styles?

Comment: @julmot try 
$('<style>body{background:red;}</style>').appendTo('head');
or
$('head').append('<style>body{background:red;}</style>');

Comment: I've already tried it. This will not work in IE8. I've solved it with ``document.createStylesheet``

Comment: This fix is still relevant on scenarios which use iframes - in my case Corner Stone On Demand (CSOD) LMS. The CSS need to be loaded dynamically, but it failed to load on IE9 (shows 404 error). Earlier I used `$('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=' + stylePath + '>').appendTo("head");` but solution by @ekerner fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

This also seems to work in IE:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.href = '/includes/style.css';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

Answer (score 2):

This might also have something to do with it - Taken from [Microsoft Support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262161):

> Styles on a webpage are missing or look incorrect when the page loads in the versions of Microsoft Internet Explorer 
>   ...
>
> ...This problem occurs because the
>   following conditions are true in
>   Internet Explorer:
>
> - All style tags
>     after the first 31 style tags are not
>     applied.
> - All style rules after the
>     first 4,095 rules are not applied.
> - On
>     pages that uses the @import rule to
>     continously import external style
>     sheets that import other style sheets,
>     style sheets that are more than three
>     levels deep are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that

```
$('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + url + '" />').appendTo('head');
```

works also in IE as long as the url is a fully qualified URI including the protocol...

Answer (score 0):

Open ie8 without the debugger open. When you get to after the point of dynamic stylesheet... open the debugger  and voila, they should be there.