# How to conditionally load a lot of web fonts?

Tags: javascript, fonts

I am building a custom sign generator for a neon sign company.  I need to show a preview of several lines of text and there is 50-60 different fonts.  I have converted all the fonts into web fonts.

I need to somehow load in the fonts as needed so that every font is not loaded (60 of them).  Is this possible?  Or any ideas on a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

Make a separate stylesheet for each font definition. Add the stylesheets to the DOM as required.

See: [How to load CSS using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913359/how-to-load-css-using-jquery/3913426#3913426)