# Prevent jquery from changing URLs when fetching css files with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

When I run:

```
$('#id').load('http://example.com/css.css');
```

I get all the css properties inside css.css, but if the file is having a protocol-relative source url, for example:

```
.logo { background-image: url('//www.foo.com/logo.png'); }
```

The response text will be:

```
.logo { background-image: url('www.foo.com//www.foo.com/logo.png'); }
```

I am willing to get the css file as is, without overwriting any of the URLs inside it.

Comment: Are you sure you are not doing some elaborations (i.e. regular expression replacements) to the string retrieved from load function? I've just tried a similar example and everything works fine. Could you please post your complete css file?

Comment: Will one of the other methods of loading CSS work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913359/how-to-load-css-using-jquery