# Jquery selector for <link> elements in <head>

Tags: jquery, dom

We use jQuery to parse some HTML. I then need to traverse that document and find some elements. Among the elements I need to find, there are the `<link>` elements.

This works perfectly well to extract all the `<a>` elements:

```
$(string).find("a")
```

but this doesn't work to extract the `<link>` elements :

```
$(string).find("link")
```

The `string` parameter is the html content (e.g. received on a request).

Any idea why? (I guess that the `find` only applies to the `<body>` elements). Also, any idea on how to actually extract these `<link>` elements?

Comment: What's in the `string` variable?

Comment: is `string` a dump of HTML you'd like to parse through?

Comment: Can you provide more info? `$('link')` works fine in a broad sense, so  that doesn't seem to be an issue.

Comment: @BoltClock : a string (!) representation of an HTML document.

Comment: I don't get this.. `$('<html><head><link rel="1"></head><body><p name="john">John</p></body></html>')` returns `[<link rel=​"1">​, <p name=​"john">​John​</p>​]`, but `$('<html><head><link rel="1"></head><body><p name="john">John</p></body></html>').find('p')` gets nothing.

Comment: @josh.trow: Read my answer. Stop trying to rationalise the browser's behaviour here: this approach is not supported. All bets are off when you try it.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: The fact that it 'finds' both elements makes me wonder about that though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) of the feature you're using for `$(string)` (which is the function `jQuery( html, [ownerDocument] )`):

> When passing in complex HTML, some
>   browsers may not generate a DOM that
>   exactly replicates the HTML source
>   provided. As mentioned, we use the
>   browser's .innerHTML property to parse
>   the passed HTML and insert it into the
>   current document. **During this process,
>   some browsers filter out certain
>   elements such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or
>   `<head>` elements.** As a result, the
>   elements inserted may not be
>   representative of the original string
>   passed.

Try not to use jQuery to manipulate *entire* HTML documents.

Note, in particular, that a `link` node in a standalone snippet of HTML [can be "found" just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/je6mD/).

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Well, based on what I can find in the [source code of jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L440-482), the engine itself will not create tags (or fragments) that are not "properly seated". Even when passing a string, jQuery recognizes that the header has already been supplied and will not generate it.</strike>

After all, when jQuery is passed a string of HTML, it's actually calling `document.createElement` and creating an array list of those elements.

**EDIT**: After a little more investigation, it looks like it's the browser actually limiting element creation, not jQuery. Either way, you're left with absent tags. Which brings me to my same conclusion below.

As much as I don't like it, may be time for regex/string manipulation.

Comment: If you inspect element the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AqbvV/) you'll see a lot of the header tags have been exempted from being generated (and you can't traverse what isn't there).

Comment: No, it's not jQuery's fault. Read the documentation.

Comment: @Tomalak: I was actually geting more in to it, and appears to be some-what a browser limitation. The browser strips tags it finds shouldn't exist/already exist. So you're most-likely correct.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can't do it, but your browser can: (Do not try to parse HTML with a regex as someome suggested.)

```
txt = '<DIV><LINK>a</LINK><B>jelo</B></DIV>';

if(window.DOMParser) {
  parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
} else { // Internet Explorer
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async="false";
  xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
}

xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('LINK');
```

Be aware that XML is case sensitive, so you need to search for 'LINK' using the same case as it is in the HTML.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either as the DOMParser is not able to parse HTML which is not valid XML :(

Comment: That is true. I guess you need to parse random HTML from any website? In that case your only option (besides writing your own parser, or using one someone else made) is a hidden iframe (but you need to watch out since the iframe will run code). You should probably google for a javascript HTML parser, I did and I found a bunch.

Answer (score -2):

Like @pimvdb pointed, this don't work:

```
alert($("<div><link>Test</link></div>").find("link").text());
```

The explanation is right:

> Sizzle uses context.getElementsByTagName, which fails because the elements are not in the DOM.

But this way work:

```
alert(("link", $("<div><link>Test</link></div>")).text());
```

And for some guys that said the second isn't working: http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/5Qs3M/. But of course it obviously don't find elements that aren't on the DOM (i.e. on the `head`).

Comment: The first does not work because it is not appended to the DOM. The second works because you missed the `$` and therefore not using the `link` selector at all.

Comment: @pimvdb: The first should work, I think. You're right about the second.

Comment: Sizzle uses `context.getElementsByTagName`, which fails because the elements are not in the DOM. Furthermore, a `<link>` cannot contain text like this because it is never holding `innerHTML` like this.

Comment: The first doesn't work because you're trying to get the `text` of a tag that should be empty. `<Link>` tags aren't meant to have content like that. jQuery seems to strip it.

Comment: If your explanation were correct, [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/5Qs3M/1/) would work. The problem is not with `innerText`, the problem is simply what was explained that the tag will not be in the document and therefore not be located.