# jQuery not parsing HTML returned from AJAX request

Tags: jquery, html, xml, ajax, meta-tags

I'm parsing some XML returned back from an AJAX request but I have a special case I have to check for before parsing. Sometimes the server will return some HTML and I need to perform a reload on the page if this is the case. The problem is that when I try to do a simple check for the META tag that's in the head element, I keep getting nothing returned.

Below is an example of the html that is returned.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Redirection</title>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" URL="https://testurl/desktop"/> 
    <META HTTP-EQUIV=Pragma CONTENT=no-cache>
    </head>
</html/>
```

The below is a snippet of the jQuery that I'm using to try and debug. The xml var is what's returned from the success method of the $.ajax() call.

```
parseXml(xml) {
    $(xml).parent().find('META').each(function() {
        location.reload();
    });
}
```

The .find() method never finds the META tag and exits and causes my code to break. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Here is the ajax call with 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '?action=someAction&target=someTarget',
        success: function(response) {
            try {
                var orders = parseXml(response);
            }
    });

Here is sample xml that I usually get back

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ORDERS>
    <ORDER STATUS="OPEN" ID="62452254" DATE="May 5" />
    <ORDER STATUS="FILLED" ID="341411" DATE="May 8" />
</ORDERS>
```

Comment: Need to see your full ajax options.

Comment: It also depends on how your xml is structured. Can you also show xml

Comment: I edited the initial post to include ajax options and sample xml

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need .parent(), and you probably need to pull out the URL attribute inside the function.

EDIT:
Grabbing more space to experiment from comments:

```
alert(xml);
var h = $(xml).html();
alert(h);
```

The former alert shows the content, the latter alert shows `null`.  [Jquery selector for <link> elements in <head>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417157/jquery-selector-for-link-elements-in-head) seems to have an elegant answer in the accepted answer:

From the [jQuery] documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM
>   that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, we use
>   the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the passed HTML and insert
>   it into the current document. During this process, some browsers
>   filter out certain elements such as , , or 
>   elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative
>   of the original string passed.

Comment: I removed parent and it still doesn't work. The URL is meaningless, but even when I do try to read it as an attribute it is undefined.

Comment: Wow, that's weird.  I renamed the html node to be httml, and it works like a charm.  But when it's named html, then .find() doesn't get it.  That's some elegantly weird voodoo.

Comment: So do you think jQuery can not parse this bit of data or use any selectors on it? Any possible workaround?