# Read Style properties from external style sheet (from file)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, stylesheet

I want to read the styles from class, and the styles are defined in external style sheet. Also I will add the external sheet dynamically.

I can able to access if it is in same html file and if it is define inside the  tag.

```
    function getStyle(className) {
        var classes = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
        debugger;
        var styles="";
        for (var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {
            if (classes[x].selectorText == className) {
                styles=((classes[x].cssText) ? classes[x].cssText : classes[x].style.cssText)+"\n";
            }
        }
return styles;
    }
```

But I need to read all the class and their style from external file, I am trying like below

```
var classfl="anaglyph";
$("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rancho&effect="+classfl+"'>");

var clsname="font-effect-anaglyph";
alert(getStyle("'"+clsname+"'"));
```

I can't able to read that class, the  tag class only I can read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load it using the `onload` handler. This will be called when the stylesheet has completed loading. Continue from inside the handler.

(It's important to define the load handler before adding the link element to head as when added the load process will start).

## Example

I extracted attributes to make it more readable, modify as needed -
(Remember to also handle errors, ie. `onerror`).

```js
$("head").append(
  $("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>")
    .attr("href", "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css")
    .on("load", cssLoaded)
);

function cssLoaded(e) {
  alert("wee...");    // the sheet has loaded, continue from here
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Vanilla JS version -**

```js
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.type = "text/css";
link.onload = cssLoaded;
link.href = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css";

// add to head to start loading...
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link)

function cssLoaded(e) {
  alert("wee...");   // the sheet has loaded, continue from here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after appending a stylesheet to the header it is not loaded yet. The javascript continues even if its not ready yet.

I think this will help: [jQuery Append CSS File and Wait until Loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767212/jquery-append-css-file-and-wait-until-loaded)