# jQuery Append CSS File and Wait until styles are applied without setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I load CSS by:

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css" />');
```

It works, but I have a function that needs to run after the CSS has been applied, and I don't want use `setInterval` for it.

How can I do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8767297/3344111 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/26169508/3344111

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Append CSS File and Wait until Loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767212/jquery-append-css-file-and-wait-until-loaded)

Comment: @CVers, none of the solutions in the *could be dupe* does deal with OP's requirements : "don't use setInterval", accepted answer does this, and "wait until styles are applied", second answer only waits for the document has loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution, if you've got access to the css file you're loading,
 is to use the [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event, and to activate a transition, with `duration` set to 0.1,  from your css.

Like so, you are sure the CSS has been calculated.

**style2.css**

```
 body{opacity:1;}
```

**index.html**

```
<style>
    body{transition : opacity 0.1s linear; opacity:.9};
</style>
<body>
   ...
<script>
    document.body.addEventListener('transitionend', function(){
        alert('done');
       }, false);
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css" />');
```

---

Edit:
For the ones that would need a js function (without external files) : https://jsfiddle.net/t0akchuw/

Comment: Hi @Kaiido, I have a question, If in 0.1s the css file can not apply, the transitionend will not be firing. And I can not make sure time to load css file?

Comment: I think that transitions are calculated last, can't be sure though but I think it shouldn't occur, does it?

Comment: Good one! There's a minor typo I wanted to correct ('transtionend' to 'transitionend') but I can't because it's a change of less than 6 chars.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Stylesheet_load_events)

```js
$('<link />', {
  rel: 'stylesheet',
  ref: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css',
  type: 'text/css',
  onload: function() {
    snippet.log('loaded')
  }
}).appendTo('head')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

Another syntax

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" onload="dosomething()" />');

function dosomething(){
    alert('d')
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case it will be call onload() when sent request, but it not is load css completed