# Adding Stylesheet with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have read up on it and it seems like the best method to add a stylesheet using jQuery is the following:

```
 $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/mystyle.css">');
```

Now what I would like to do, is switch between different themes using this method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          if($('body').hasClass('pink'))
          {
              $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/mystylePink.css">');
          }
          else
          {
              $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/mystyle.css">');
          }
      });
</script>
```

**MY QUESTION**: 
Apart form users not having javascript enabled, what complications/issues exists when loading a stylesheet like this? IE? Mobile browsers? Since I actually want to use this on a mobile site...

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here would be the flash of unstyled content while the stylesheet loads, rather than IE or mobile browsers.

I suggest you use a CSS preprocessor (SASS, LESS) and just use one stylesheet with your normal styles and then override with the `.pink` class underneath.

```
.myClass{
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

.pink .myClass{
  color: pink;
  background: grey;
}
```

Comment: yeah I agree, thank you. Problem is that I have have many styles that do not use classes and uses element targeting: eg #wrapper ul li a{}, and I do not want to add styles to my existing html elements. So what I can do, is load a stylesheet to start of with, and then replace it with another one once the document is ready....Then of course there is preloading with window.onload  - show a loading gif while everything is loading

Comment: SASS/LESS will take care of specific element targeting.

Comment: ok cool, i see thank you...What about compatibility other than IE? Is it reliable and safe to use my method?

Answer (score 1):

This method isnt't working in IE8 and below.

You have to use another method, like IEss document.createStyleSheet() method.

See this discussion for more information: [Can I load external stylesheets on request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126238/load-external-stylesheets-on-request)