# How to avoid CSS conflict using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am experiencing a CSS conflict issue.
Here are the details:

I have a search results page in which products are shown in grid format. The CSS for that is grid search results is "product-grid.css" which is included header of the page. On this page I have button which when clicked shows the search results in list format. The css for list format is "product-list.css" which is also included in head tag of the page.

Now the HTML guy has made the name of classes to be same in both product-grid.css and product-list.css.

What I want is that when I am viewing the page in grid style only product-grid.css should apply to respective portion of the page. And when I am viewing the page in list format then product-grid.css should be disabled and product-list.css should apply on whole page.

I have tried enabling and disabling css files using jquery but may be I am doing something wrong. Also when the page loads both css files are active in head tag and due to conflict in classes names the page is malformed even without shifting to other view.

Any help what should I do?

Comment: Could you please add your code that is switching the styles ?

Comment: You probably use PHP or something to load your content. Why not use it to manage which stylesheet should be loaded, based on the URL... Or even better, rename the classes, so duplicates won't exist!

Comment: Consider rephrasing your question title

Comment: What determines whether you should be viewing it in grid or list?  Couldn't you just use CSS media queries to toggle your styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a variable which decides about the condition that page is viewing either in grid style or in list style. On the basis of that variable use the code below.

As per your condition you need to verify that if page is viewing in grid style then add grid
css like

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="product-grid.css.css">');
```

else

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="product-list.css">');
```

Ref: [Can I load external stylesheets on request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126238/can-i-load-external-stylesheets-on-request)

Comment: Whole page is not in this way. On click only part of page changes via ajax call.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution:

> *The HTML guy* should change the class names. Current approach is **unacceptable**.

Doing *workarounds* and *abracadabras* with CSS files loading just because some guy was to lazy to separate the significant parts of the page is simply **stupid**, IMHO.