# Dynamically Created HTML object not having CSS applied to it

Tags: javascript, html, css, appendchild, createelement

Final product: Web page that is filled in by data on a word document which is fed into a recurring HTML structure.

Problem: When ran, the HTML elements are created, but the *CSS classes are not applied until the window is resized.*

Javascrip:

```
    for (i=0; i<=timeline_data.length; i++){
        var newParent = document.getElementById('wgt-timeline-bdy-wrap-id');
        var newItem = document.createElement('div');
        newParent.appendChild(newItem);
        newItem.setAttribute('class','wgt-timeline-bdy-item');

        var newText = document.createElement('p');
        newItem.appendChild(newText);
        newText.setAttribute('class','timeline-new-text');
        newText.id="timeline-" + timeline_data[i].id + "-text";

    }
```

CSS:

```
.wgt-timeline-bdy-item {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}

.timeline-new-text{
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top:40px;
}
```

Nothing unexpected in the HTML, wgt-timeline-bdy-wrap-id is a div.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Where exactly in your code is that `for` loop located? Can you post the entire script?

Comment: Are you putting the CSS in the body instead of the head? That may not be it but I have seen that happen before like that.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem? CSS should work just as well with dynamic content as static.

Comment: In fact, that's one of the points of CSS. Many applications change the style of elements by dynamically changing their classes.

Comment: Unless 'i' is defined elsewhere you may want to change 'i=0' to be 'var i=0'; After adding that the code ran fine for me. Is the css included in the file (link or style block)? And what browsers have you tried?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that there's a typo somewhere, so the classes don't match.

Comment: @Barmar The only reason I could think of without seeing the entire code is that the for loop is probably present within a `window.resize` function because OP says the classes get applied when resized.

Comment: For loop located in a function called onload of the body, CSS is located is a separate functioning .css file (other elements are working from it therefore I know thats not the problem) I shall go find out what jsfiddle is now. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: there is no window.resize function

Comment: there is no type because it would not have functioned once i resized the page

Comment: @Harry But the loop is also where the new elements get created. If it were inside a particular event handler, the elements wouldn't show up at all until that event.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

try appending to the DOM as the last thing you do in the loop (i.e after you have set the class).  Also, most places I've done this through `element.className = 'xxx'` rather than using the `setAttribute()` function; not sure that matters, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a jQuery function to apply the CSS styles once the for loop is done executing.  Something like this:

```
for{...}
styleelements();

function styleelements(){
$(".wgt-timeline-bdy-item").css({...});
$(".timeline-new-text").css({...});
}
```

Comment: Why exactly is jQuery required for this case?

Comment: Well, you could use javascripts .style function, but I find jQuery to usually be faster and easier.

Comment: It's not; folks just like to use it b/c they don't have to know the browser specific stuff.

Comment: Having to copy all your CSS into your script is an onerous requirement. That means that every time they update the CSS file they'll have to make the same changes to the jQuery. There's no reason this should be necessary.

Comment: @colinmcp: If the user was trying to do something complex then using a library which handles all possible browsers etc is understandable. But you don't really need jQuery to add/remove classes.

Comment: @Harry Fair, I didn't think of that.  Maybe instead of applying the CSS directly after the for loop executes, you could load the stylesheet after the for loop executes?  Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126238/can-i-load-external-stylesheets-on-request)