# Can I have more than 1 Responsive CSS stylesheet for one document? If so, How?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to make multiple responsive css stylesheets for one document. So I do:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="responsive.css" media="screen and (max-width: 900px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="responsive_1056.css" media="screen and (max-width: 1056px)">
```

Once it reaches 1056, the responsive_1056.css file is executed. But once it reaches 900px, the responsive.css (max-width: 900px) is not executed.

Is there a reason why this happens? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Responsive.css is probably being picked up, but then overwritten by the data in responsive_1056.css

Editing the last link to include (min-width : 900px) should do the job.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="responsive_1056.css" media="screen (min-width : 900px) and (max-width: 1056px)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways: First, just open up each of the files and put the media query inside!  Just have the whole stylesheet wrapped in a media query.  at the beginning put:

```
screen and (max-width: 1056px){
...all your styles here...
}
```

Or you could use jQuery to load each individually.  On page load check for the width of the document:

```
width = $(window).width();
var sheetToLoad;
if(width > 1056)
    sheetToLoad = "big.css"
elseif(width <1056 && width > 900)
    sheetToLoad = "medium.css"
else
    sheetToLoad = "small.css"

$.ajax(...) //load stylesheet "sheetToLoad"

//Or just see this link
```

[Can I load external stylesheets on request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126238/can-i-load-external-stylesheets-on-request)