# Defining icons in the contextMenu plugin of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, contextmenu

So far, I was able to create a contextMenu that binds to a right mouse cilck by including the javascript in a html file:

```
var Feature = {
    register_contextMenu: function() {
        $.contextMenu({
            selector: '*',
            items: {
                "item_one": { name: "Item_one", icon: "./path1" },
                "item_two": { name: "item_two", icon: "./path2" }
            }
        });
    }
};

$(document).ready(Feature.register_contextMenu);
```

How would one go about displaying icons alongside the options?

The documentation of the plugin(http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/) mentions that one has to define icons in CSS with certain selectors.

How does one use CSS with contextMenu in this case?

Comment: `{name: "item_two",  icon: "./path2")` ? Don't you mean: `{name: "item_two",  icon: "./path2"}` You are also missing a closing brace...

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Indeed, I edited.

Comment: Alright, I added the closing brace.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I am still working on applying it, in particular the part on adding the icons.

Comment: See my demo below. The "`icon`" property is a class-name, not a path. The class will define the background image.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you check out the [source code](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html) for the demo on Github?

Looks like you just add a CSS class:

```css
.context-menu-item.icon-<NAME-OF-ICON> {
    background-image: url(images/<NAME-OF-ICON>.png);
}
```

The docs also state:

> (*string*) icon
> Specifies the icon class to set for the item.
>
> Icons must be defined in CSS with selectors like .context-menu-item.icon-edit, where edit is the icon class.

The create() function is responsible for attaching the class for the icons to the items. This code appears on *line 1077* of the current [source code](https://github.com/medialize/jQuery-contextMenu/blob/master/src/jquery.contextMenu.js).

```js
// add icons
if (item.icon) {
     $t.addClass("icon icon-" + item.icon);
}
```

From the demo:

```css
/* icons
    #protip:
    In case you want to use sprites for icons (which I would suggest you do) have a look at
    http://css-tricks.com/13224-pseudo-spriting/ to get an idea of how to implement 
    .context-menu-item.icon:before {}
 */
.context-menu-item.icon { min-height: 18px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 4px 2px; }
.context-menu-item.icon-edit { background-image: url(images/page_white_edit.png); }
.context-menu-item.icon-cut { background-image: url(images/cut.png); }
.context-menu-item.icon-copy { background-image: url(images/page_white_copy.png); }
.context-menu-item.icon-paste { background-image: url(images/page_white_paste.png); }
.context-menu-item.icon-delete { background-image: url(images/page_white_delete.png); }
.context-menu-item.icon-add { background-image: url(images/page_white_add.png); }
.context-menu-item.icon-quit { background-image: url(images/door.png); }
```

---

### Demo

I removed the "edit", "delete", and "add" menu-items from the [example](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html) and added a "Share on Google+", "Share on Facebook", and "Save" option to the menu.

Just press "Run code snippet" below to see it in action.

```js
$(function(){
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one', 
    callback: function(key, options) {
      var m = "clicked: " + key;
      window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
    },
    items: {
      "cut"      : { name: "Cut",               icon: "cut" },
      "copy"     : { name: "Copy",              icon: "copy" },
      "paste"    : { name: "Paste",             icon: "paste" },
      "sep1"     : "---------",
      "google"   : { name: "Share on Google+",  icon: "google-plus" },
      "facebook" : { name: "Share on Facebook", icon: "facebook" },
      "sep2"     : "---------",
      "save"     : { name: "Save",              icon: "save" },
      "quit"     : { name: "Quit",              icon: "quit" }
    }
  });

  $('.context-menu-one').on('click', function(e){
    console.log('clicked', this);
  })
});
```

```css
.context-menu-icon {
  min-height: 18px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 4px 2px;
}

.context-menu-icon-save {
  /* Source: http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/icons/disk.png */
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/4LyeGi1.png");
}

.context-menu-icon-facebook {
  /* Source: http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yootheme/social-bookmark/16/social-facebook-box-blue-icon.png */
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/EVcCwyZ.png");
}

.context-menu-icon-google-plus {
  /* Source: https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/professional-toolbar-icons-2/16/Google_plus_google.png */
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/Zg0UFmq.png");
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu/master/dist/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu/master/dist/jquery.contextMenu.js"></script>

<div class="context-menu-one box menu-1">
  <strong>Right-Click ME!</strong>
</div>
```

---

## Update

I suggest that you use a font icon library such as FontAwesome. This is the easiest solution.

```js
$(function(){
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one', 
    callback: function(key, options) {
      var msg = "clicked: " + key;
      window.console && console.log(msg) || alert(msg); 
    },
    items: {
      "cut"      : { name: "Cut",               icon: "cut" },
      "copy"     : { name: "Copy",              icon: "copy" },
      "paste"    : { name: "Paste",             icon: "paste" },
      "sep1"     : "---------",
      "google"   : { name: "Share on Google+",  icon: "google-plus" },
      "facebook" : { name: "Share on Facebook", icon: "facebook" },
      "sep2"     : "---------",
      "save"     : { name: "Save",              icon: "save" },
      "quit"     : { name: "Quit",              icon: "quit" }
    }
  });

  $('.context-menu-one').on('click', function(e){
    console.log('clicked', this);
  })
});
```

```css
.context-menu-icon.context-menu-icon-save:before,
.context-menu-icon.context-menu-icon-facebook:before,
.context-menu-icon.context-menu-icon-google-plus:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome !important;
}

.context-menu-icon.context-menu-icon-save:before {
  content: "\f0c7"; /* fa-floppy-o */
}

.context-menu-icon.context-menu-icon-facebook:before {
  content: "\f230"; /* fa-facebook-official */
}

.context-menu-icon.context-menu-icon-google-plus:before {
  content: "\f0d4"; /* fa-google-plus-square */
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu/master/dist/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu/master/dist/jquery.contextMenu.js"></script>

<div class="context-menu-one box menu-1">
  <strong>Right-Click ME!</strong>
</div>
```

It looks like FontAwesome is supported with this plugin, so you do not need to customize any CSS.

```js
$(function(){
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one', 
    callback: function(key, options) {
      var msg = "clicked: " + key;
      window.console && console.log(msg) || alert(msg); 
    },
    items: {
      "cut"      : { name: "Cut",               icon: "cut" },
      "copy"     : { name: "Copy",              icon: "copy" },
      "paste"    : { name: "Paste",             icon: "paste" },
      "sep1"     : "---------",
      "google"   : { name: "Share on Google+",  icon: "fa-google-plus-square" },
      "facebook" : { name: "Share on Facebook", icon: "fa-facebook-official" },
      "sep2"     : "---------",
      "save"     : { name: "Save",              icon: "fa-floppy-o" },
      "quit"     : { name: "Quit",              icon: "quit" }
    }
  });

  $('.context-menu-one').on('click', function(e){
    console.log('clicked', this);
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu/master/dist/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu/master/dist/jquery.contextMenu.js"></script>

<div class="context-menu-one box menu-1">
  <strong>Right-Click ME!</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: What is precisely meant with the name of the icon? Is it sufficient to give its path?

Comment: The same for `item.icon`: where do we define `item.icon`?

Comment: Could you elaborate on adding part of the icons?

Comment: I added a demo above. Can you accept this answer, as it satisfies your question.

Comment: I still do not have a minimum working example: I think the problem lies in adding the CSS file. I now use `$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssfile.css" type="text/css" />');`, but it does not seem to work: there are no icons displayed.

Comment: That is a totally different question. I have already answered your question. Please see this question: [Can I load external stylesheets on request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126238/can-i-load-external-stylesheets-on-request) to answer the one you just asked.

Comment: Fair enough, however my example still does not work. I think adding the CSS file is not the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It has been a while since you asked for help... Anyway, try to adapt the following code (It just sums up Mr. Polywhirl's answer into a single file for easier understanding).
As you can see, the menu's first three items contain custom icons, while the last one uses one of the built-in .svg pictures.

If you use external resources as I do in this example, make sure that you are able to access them (Open Chrome's Dev-Tools by pressing Strg + I and watch out for error messages in the console) and as always make sure that you are allowed to use them.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <!-- include the context-menu from cdnjs -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.0.1/jquery.contextMenu.min.css" />
  <style>
    .context-menu-abc {
      border: 1px solid gray;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    /* used for all items */
    
    .context-menu-item {
      min-height: 18px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 4px 4px;
    }
    /* all custom icons */
    
    .context-menu-item.context-menu-icon-firstOpt {
      background-image: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/6x16-free-application-icons/16/Boss.png");
    }
    
    .context-menu-item.context-menu-icon-secondOpt {
      background-image: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/6x16-free-application-icons/16/Save.png");
    }
    
    .context-menu-item.context-menu-icon-thirdOpt {
      background-image: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/6x16-free-application-icons/16/OK.png");
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div><span class="context-menu-abc">right-click this box</span></div>

  <!-- try to include scripts at the end so the DOM can be created faster -->
  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.0.1/jquery.contextMenu.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      "use strict";
      $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-abc',
        callback: function(key, options) {
          if (key === 'firstOpt') {
            // specific code for your first option
          } else if (key === 'secondOpt') {
            // specific code for your second option
          } else if (key === 'thirdOpt') {
            // specific code for your third option
          }
        },
        items: {
          'firstOpt': {
            name: "First option",
            icon: "firstOpt"
          },
          'secondOpt': {
            name: "Second choice",
            icon: "secondOpt"
          },
          'thirdOpt': {
            name: "Third option",
            icon: "thirdOpt"
          },
          'copy': {
            name: "Fourth option",
            icon: "copy"
          }
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Mr PolyWhirls example above I still couldn't get it to work properly. The FontAwesome icon was not aliging properly etc. I imagine that there has been an update to the plugin somewhere along the way that has broken support for FA 4. (There were changes to FA 4 when FA 5 came out). My solution was to go back to using custom CSS...

```
<style type="text/css">
    .context-menu-icon.context-menu-icon-file-alt:before {
        font-family: FontAwesome !important;
        color: #2980B9;
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: normal;
          font-size: 16px;
          left: 0;
          line-height: 1;
          position: absolute;
          text-align: center;
          top: 50%;
          transform: translateY(-50%);
          -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
          -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
          width: 28px;

    }
    .context-menu-icon.context-menu-icon-file-alt:before{
        content: '\f15c';
    }
</style>
```