# How to change src attribute of a stylesheet

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to change css stylesheet by clicking on a button.

```
<head>    
<link id='link01' rel="stylesheet" href="blue.css">  
</head>
```

**JS**

```
$('.pointcolors').click(function(){
    var theme = $(this).attr('data-theme') + '.css';
    console.log(theme); // green.css - it's ok
    $('#link01').attr('src', theme);
});
```

But there is no style changes. Nothing happens.
Any help?

Comment: You might be changing the URL, but that doesn't necessarily mean it'll load the new one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I load external stylesheets on request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126238/can-i-load-external-stylesheets-on-request)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think:

```
$('#link01').attr('src', theme);
```

Should be:

```
$('#link01').attr('href', theme);
```

[How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
 $('#link01').attr('src', theme);
```

To:

```
 $('#link01').attr('href', theme);
```

If you look at your link tag, the attribute that contains the filename is "href", not "src".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

> Use jQuery's [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to change the `href` property of `link` tag.

```js
$(function() {
 $("#block a").on('click', function() {
        theme = $(this).data('theme');
  $("#link01").attr("href", theme + '.css');
        console.log("Stylesheet changed to: " + $("#link01").attr("href"));
  return false;
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link id='link01' rel="stylesheet" href="blue.css">  
<div id="block">
  <a href="#" data-theme="green">Change Stylesheet Link</a>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Changing `src` to `href` should work.

```
$('#link01').attr('href', theme);
```