# loadeing CSS after page loading using jQuery to accomplish that

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to load CSS after the page is don from loading HTML and javascript. to fix render-blocking CSS and I tried that with jquery but I'm not finding a way to do that to be more specific I have more than one stylesheet.
I find this code but I have more than one stylesheet

```
url = 'style.css';
if (document.createStyleSheet)
{
   document.createStyleSheet(url);
} 
else
{
    $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + url + '" 
  />').appendTo('head');   
}
```

Comment: Can you provide any code, so we can see?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/2126255/752527

Comment: You want to load your page, then render it, then style it. Is this really what you want? This is not a good UX.

Comment: Load the js then the css with normal links. Js will block rendering.