# Drupal - special css file if JS is turned off?

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, drupal-6, themes

I'm building a Drupal theme up and want to know if there is a Drupalish way to add a css file only if the user has js turned off.

This would ideally go in the theme.info file to keep it neat!

Something like this would be ideal:

```
conditional-stylesheets[if no javascript][all][] = nojs.css
```

If this isn't possible then I'm going to keep all the css that needs JS out of the css files, and add it dynamically using JS but this seems a bit messy...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need conditional comments or noscript-tags for that. By default, Drupal adds a 'js' class to the html element and sets a cookie if javascript is enabled:

```
// Global Killswitch on the <html> element
if (Drupal.jsEnabled) {
  // Global Killswitch on the <html> element
  $(document.documentElement).addClass('js');
  // 'js enabled' cookie
  document.cookie = 'has_js=1; path=/';
  // Attach all behaviors.
  $(document).ready(function() {
  Drupal.attachBehaviors(this);
  });
 }
```

(That's on line 296 in /misc/drupal.js.)

All css selectors that should only apply when js is enabled, can be prefixed with `.js`. If you want, you can put those css rules in a separate file, but you don't have to.

Comment: Thats brilliant. Thanks for the answer and I'm sure it will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know drupal that well, but it's a good question either way. According to W3Schools, the `<noscript>` tag is allowed only within the `body` element, so that is out.

Have you considered doing it the other way round? i.e. adding a script-specific CSS stylesheet using JavaScript? See starting points for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184950/dynamically-loading-css-stylesheet-doesnt-work-on-ie).

Comment: That looks interesting but I think in my particular project using something like jquery css() would be more appropriate - http://api.jquery.com/css/