# jquery: replace the link to style.css to game.css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, replace

Trying to replace the conents of a whole page ( works ) + also replace the link to a style.css to game.css, with query

```
$.get('/games/14', function(data){  var $page = $(data);
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css" />');
    //$('#layout').empty().append($page);
    $('body').empty().append($page);
})
```

I seem to be unable to change the "style.css" to "game.css" no matter what I try, wich Jquery Guru knows how to accomplish this? thx !

UPDATE:
tried the suggestions below still have issues, this is what I'm using now ( no replacement of the .css file )

```
  $.get('/games/14', function(data){
$("link[href='style.css']").attr({href: 'game.css'});
var $page = $(data);
$('body').empty().append($page);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ya go, just tested this out and it worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="/assets/frontend.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $("link[href='/assets/frontend.css']").attr('href', '/assets/game.css');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

To anwer your comment below, I tested it using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).
Using the Console tab, I can see that it first attempted to load up **assets/frontend.css**, ran the JS, then attempted to load up **assets/game.css**.

[image: loading]

I then checked the DOM in the HTML tab of firebug, and saw that the link elements href attribute was updated.

[image]

Comment: also doesn't work for me how did you test it? I've i save this as .html it still shows the frontend.css when try to load page, view source .

Comment: Clicking 'view source' in a browser will *not* show you the *current* state of the page's DOM. It will show you the document first pulled from the server. I.e., the *original* file, without any changes you've made using JavaScript. I suggest using something like the Chrome/Safari Web Inspector or Firebug for Firefox.

Comment: Edd Morgan is correct. Simply viewing source will not show you anything that has updated since the initial loading of the DOM. I've updated answer with an explanation of how I tested it for ya.

Comment: I checked it with firebug also, it seems to working indeed, thx for the complete writeup. I assumed the html would in reality be changed and rewritten but this seems not the case, although ineed it tries to  load the game.css wich would answer the question competletly. Im not that of a query coder myself thx for helping out getting this fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Target the link element with href attribute 'style.css' and replace the href attribute of that element with 'game.css':

```
$("link[href='style.css']").attr({href: 'game.css'});
```

Comment: Ok I tried these myself to no avail, I'm trying to replace this <link href="/assets/frontend.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> with "/assets/game.css" any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `attr()` function to change the href.

```
$("link[href=style.css]").attr('href', 'game.css');
```

There's probably a more rock-solid selector you'll want to use, but that'll do it.

Comment: The syntax above is correct. Make sure the "style.css" in the jQuery selector *matches* the `link`'s href that you are trying to replace -- and that the "game.css" in the `attr()` call matches the address to the stylesheet you're trying to change it to. Also, make sure the original `link` element actually exists. In your question edit, it seems you've removed the call you used to insert the `link` element in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

`href` attribute substitution as suggested in other answers is inconsistently handled by different browsers (i.e. may not trigger re-flow/re-render). Instead, the original style element has to be removed and a new element with the desired `href` has to be inserted in its place. An intuitive way to do so with jQuery:

```
$('link[href$="style.css"]').replaceWith('<link href="game.css" ... ></link>');
```

Comment: Which browsers is it inconsistently handled by? I just tested it out in IE7, IE8, IE9, FF, Safari, and Chrome. It worked as expected in all of them.

Comment: @CodyBonney: hearsay, but I always worked under the assumption that IE7&8 will mess this up; like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3007669/1081234