# dynamic CSS loading in IE won't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a button in my page, and onclick event, if should append to the `<head>` a CSS file from a server and do something else.
it works perfectly in FF but in IE, it seems not to work (it did append the `<link>` to the `<head>` - but the CSS won't affect the elements)

Heres my current code:

```
function loadDynamicCss(filename) {
    var fileref = document.createElement("link")
    fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
    fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}
```

What can cause this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to reload the same stylesheet?

Comment: Is this a simple IE caching issue? Have you tried pasting the url from the appended link tag into IE's URL field, then reloading the page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184950/dynamically-loading-css-stylesheet-doesnt-work-on-ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function:

```
function include_css(url) {
var page = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        cssElem = document.createElement('link');

        cssElem.setAttribute('rel', 'css');
        cssElem.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
        cssElem.setAttribute('href', url);

        page.appendChild(cssElem);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me when views are rendered post factum with ejs.

Comment: @Himberjack: Can you confirm that this solution worked for you?