# How to append Style Sheets in IE using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

**Hello Guys,**

I was just trying to create a plugin, and I needed it to be user-friendly so I want to `append` the `<link/>` tag on the `head` portion of the users page as my plugin is loaded. It works fine with all the other browsers (not sure of IE9, IE7 & IE6) but doesn't work for IE8!
I don't what is getting wrong with my plugin, so I just created a sample page and faced the similar problem! Here is my test page HTML+jQuery Code ------

```
<html>
       <head>
              <script src="../jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
              <script>
                       $(document).ready(function () {
                          $(document.head).append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />');
                       });
              </script>
       </head>
       <body>
              <h1>Text!</h1>
       </body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS code -----

```
body {
 background:#ddd; 
}
h1 {
 color: #789; 
}
```

So can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong or is this the problem of lifetime?

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**

---

After seeing the first comment and going to link supplied, I just created this sample code and found something amazing! See this ~~~

```
<html>
       <head>
              <script src="../jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
              <script>
                       $(document).ready(function () {
                          if (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] === document.head) {
                           $("head").append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />');
                          }else {
                           alert('This doesn\'t supports head appending!');
                          }
                       });
              </script>
       </head>
       <body>
              <h1>Text!</h1>
       </body>
</html>
```

On executing this page with my IE8 browser I get the message that

```
This doesn't supports head appending!
```

Well I don't what is wrong with my browser or is this the fault of IE8?

---

Comment: Dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184950/dynamically-loading-css-stylesheet-doesnt-work-on-ie

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
if (document.createStyleSheet)
{
    document.createStyleSheet("style.css");
}
else
{
    $("head")
       .append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />'); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy you rock ~ this works with every browser in the world! Thanks again!

Comment: This seems like something that should actually be a part of jquery when attempting to add HTML that includes a link tag in IE < 9.

Comment: I agree, this should be part of jquery.

Comment: I was caught out by the fact that the IE8 compatibility mode in IE9 **does** let you insert a link into the head, but the real IE8 doesn't. So much for 'compatibility'! I agree, this should be in jquery.

Answer (score 5):

You're using `document.head` to access the head. `document.head`  is only a recent addition to the DOM, as part of HTML5. So, it's not universally supported.

If you want to use it, you should [add a shim](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/document-head) before calling it:

```
document.head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
```

Otherwise, you can just append directly to the `<head>` tag (which is recommended, since that's half the point of using jQuery's syntactic sugar):

```
$("head").append(...);
```

Comment: I know but it is not working, see my newest Edit to my question. IE8 doesn't supporting appending tags in `head` section!?

Comment: ...your alert merely proves that document.head isn't supported, as I said, not that you can't append to the head via JavaScript. If you add the shim, it should work. `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]` has universal support.

Comment: Then how to append `link` tag on it? Please help me out.

Comment: @Jack Billy: If you are OK with vanilla JavaScript, I have a code snippet. But I guess you know how to do it with js.

Comment: Please provide everything you got to answer my question ~~ ace