# jQuery $('head:first').prepend('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + absUrl + '" />') does not work in IE

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following JS code which I call in different places to include CSS styles:

```
<script>    
    $('head:first').prepend('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css" />')
}
</script>
```

It works in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE. IE just doesn't load CSS styles from this file. However,

```
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />');
```

works in IE, but does not work for my other scenarios.

How can I fix it for IE without using document.write?

Thanks

Comment: What's with the additional `}`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to append Style Sheets in IE using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079702/how-to-append-style-sheets-in-ie-using-jquery)

Comment: Felix Kling was right on. His link solved me problem. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Erm... You're trying to put the `<link>` tag BEFORE the `<head>`, when it MUST be inside it.

Use `append` instead of `prepend`.

Comment: Erm... [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/): *"Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the beginning of each element in the set of matched elements."* You are confusing it with `.before()`.

Comment: Ah. Well isn't there something in the jQuery docs about stylesheets not being able to be added properly or something?