# CSS loaded dynamically via javascript but not applied

Tags: javascript, css

I have a javascript file that load a content via AJAX and apply the appropriate style by loading the corresponding CSS file:

```
var ssioCss = document.createElement("link");
ssioCss.setAttribute("href", baseURL + "ssio-plugin.css");
ssioCss.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
document.head.appendChild(ssioCss);
```

But unfortunately, the style is not applied, event the file was correctly loaded (checked via chrome inspector).

Did I missed something? Any idea how to fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically loading css stylesheet doesn't work on IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184950/dynamically-loading-css-stylesheet-doesnt-work-on-ie)

Comment: `ssioCss.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");` *shrugs*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing something:

```
ssioCss.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
```

Otherwise there's nothing to tell the browser what to do the with the downloaded file. Just in case you're wondering, `type = "text/css"` only restricts the [MIME Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME/).

Comment: Thanks a lot Abody97, it works now. Edit: there is no 2 'b' in 'Attribute'.

Comment: @Hassinus Haha, yeah -- very sorry :)