# Dynamic loading of css files doesn't work in IE

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, razor

Almost solution I found was using javascript/jquery while on my part it should be Views in MVC. One reference is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184950/dynamically-loading-css-stylesheet-doesnt-work-on-ie)

So I set up my css files in this way:

```
@{
ViewBag.Stylesheets = new string[] {
    "global/style.css",
    "global/links.css",
    .
    .
    .
    . 40 plus more css files...
};
```

And load them:

```
@foreach (string stylesheet in
ViewBag.Stylesheets is string[] ? ViewBag.Stylesheets : new string[] { @"style.css" })
{ 
    <link href="@Url.ContentArea("~/css/" + stylesheet)" rel="stylesheet" />
}
```

All of these were inside views. I have 48 css files and I notice that IE9 loads only 37 css files. For now it is not possible to combine css codes in some number of files for certain reasons. So how can I load all of these css files in IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorer [`has a limit`](http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnetmvcteam/posts/10-05-03/internet-explorer-css-limits.aspx) of 31 CSS files per page. This limitation has been removed in IE 10.

So you have 2 possibilities if you need to support IE <= 9:

1. reorganize your CSS rules so that you have less than 31 files
2. combine them (recommended)

Answer (score 0):

The `~` is unneeded. You can just have `href="/css/file.css"`

Comment: Sure, I will remove that. But still, IE doesn't load all of my css files. But no problem in Chrome or Firefox.