# Jquery length not working on IE8

Tags: jquery

Why I´m doing it wrong?
It is not loading the amin.css and not even removing the adminNotes.css

```
if(($(".AdminNoteContainer").length <= 0)){
         $("head").append($('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />'));
         $('head *[href*="css/adminNotes.css"]').remove();
    };
```

Comment: which version of jQuery do you have?

Comment: That should work, but why not just `if ( ! $(".AdminNoteContainer").length ){...`

Comment: Try with `size()` instead of `length`

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos - Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

Comment: How can the length be `< 0`?

Comment: What makes you think its .length the problem?

Comment: @RocketHazmat it can't be, but it can be <= 0.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1184960  IE is such a horrible browser that appending (or possibly removing) a `<link>` tag doesn't affect the page.  You need to use the (IE ONLY) `document.createStyleSheet` to load in your new CSS.  As for removing an old stylesheet, I'm not sure if you can.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically loading css stylesheet doesn't work on IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184950/dynamically-loading-css-stylesheet-doesnt-work-on-ie)

Comment: Class names are case sensitive, make sure they match exactly.

Comment: Nooo it;'s not duplicate.. Please tell me that you validated your css against http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/
To me it seems like your css are not upto the mark and browser does not recognize it as css

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal - of course it is, the OP's syntax for appending stylesheets doesn't work in IE8

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not with the `.length` (though I don't know why you have `<= 0`, you can just simply do `=== 0` or even better `if(!$(".AdminNoteContainer").length)`), it's with how you're appending the CSS.

IE 8 (and even 9 I think) doesn't let you append `<link>` tags after the page is rendered.  You need to use an IE specific method to add CSS.  `document.createStyleSheet`.

I like to make  a `getStyleSheet` method that will check for the right method of appending CSS.  This will use `document.createStyleSheet` if it's there, if not it'll append a `<link>` tag.

```
$.getStyleSheet = function(url){
    if(document.createStyleSheet){
        document.createStyleSheet(url);
    }
    else{
        $('<link />', {
            type: 'text/css',
            rel: 'stylesheet',
            href: url
        }).appendTo('head');
    }
};
```

Then you can simply do:

```
if(!$(".AdminNoteContainer").length){
    $.getStyleSheet('css/main.css');
    $('head *[href*="css/adminNotes.css"]').remove();
}
```

Comment: the thing is i can remove the other stylesheet i will need to think in a different approach thanks