# Runtime error: Permission denied when using glimps on IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11, glimpse

I'm currently busy getting glimpse working for my project. On chrome it works like a charm, but when working with ie11 (desktop mode) I constantly get an JavaScript runtime error: 'Permission denied'.

The error is thrown when loading the trigger.shell.init.

I was able to locate the exact location where it goes wrong and that is in the glimpse.render.js file inside the init function. In that function CSS is added to the head and html to the body. On both methods I get the permission dinied.

```
init = function() {  
        pubsub.publish('action.template.processing', { templates: templates });
        pubsub.publish('action.shell.loading');

        $(getCss()).appendTo('head'); 
        $(getHtml()).appendTo('body');

        pubsub.publish('action.shell.loaded');
        pubsub.publish('action.template.processed', { templates: templates });

        pubsub.publish('trigger.shell.subscriptions'); 

        process(true, 'action.shell.initial'); 

        pubsub.publish('trigger.shell.ready'); 
    }
```

At that point I'm able to access the 'head' using jquery but the moment I'm trying to add something to the head or the body it goes wrong.

Does any one has any idea about what is going wrong? A solution would be ideal.

Comment: It looks like [other people have had issues adding CSS to the DOM in IE11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184950/dynamically-loading-css-stylesheet-doesnt-work-on-ie).

However, I haven't been able to replicate the problem, so I wonder what's different about your configuration. I used IE 11.0.9 and Glimpse 1.8.4. Can you add in some info about your setup?

Comment: I'm using IE 11.0.9 and Glimpse 1.8.2. I only have the issue in ASP.NET MVC. I also have a webForms part, but that works also fine

Comment: I just updated to 1.8.5 and still have the same issue.

Comment: In the same browser, do you get the same problem on the Glimpse instance installed at http://play.getglimpse.com?

Comment: Nope it seems to work fine.

Comment: Random question: Does this happen on all pages in your application? Or - really grasping here - are you doing `use strict` or anything like that in your app?

Comment: It happens on all MVC pages. And yes, all the js code we wrote has the 'use strict'.