# ASP.NET MVC how to change less variables with javascript?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, less

In my application I must add feature for the user to chnage UI colors.

For this purpose I have created .less file and set some global variables to their default value.

What is the best practice for creating theme in Asp.net MVC?

Comment: Will the user be able to select a specific color? Or will a colorscheme be sufficient aswell?

Comment: @Mark Colorscheme is sufficeint

Comment: Less is a preprocessor, its variables do not exist by the time a page is rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a base styling for the default styling and different stylesheets (less files and finally seperate .css files) for each colorscheme, each scheme overrides the colors in the base file, then dynamically load the stylesheet according to your business logic using javascript

[Dynamically loading css stylesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184950/dynamically-loading-css-stylesheet-doesnt-work-on-ie)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will do go with that way.