# Add CSS to <head> with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to add css from a string in the javascript file to the head of a document with javascript?

Let's say we have a webpage, which has a lightbox script, this script requires a css file to function.

Now adding this css file with `<link>` will make the css file download even for people that don't have js enabled.

I know that I can dynamically load the css file with the script, but that also means that there will be 2 http requests, and in cases where there is little to no css in the file I find this inefficient.

So I thought to myself, what if you could put the css that you have in the css file, into the script, have the script parse the css and add it into the head, or even better just have the script add the css directly into the `<head>` of the document.

But I have found nothing online that suggests that this is possible, so is it possible to add css to the head with js?

### Edit + SOLUTION:

I edited roryf's answer to work cross browser (except IE5)

Javascript:

```
 function addcss(css){
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var s = document.createElement('style');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    if (s.styleSheet) {   // IE
        s.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } else {                // the world
        s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }
    head.appendChild(s);
 }
```

Comment: Have a look at the following link .. It explains every little details about your question ... and it is named appropriately [Totally Pwn CSS with Javascript](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As you are trying to add a string of CSS to `<head>` with JavaScript?
 injecting a string of CSS into a page it is easier to do this with the `<link>` element than the `<style>` element.

The following adds `p { color: green; }` rule to the page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="data:text/css;charset=UTF-8,p%20%7B%20color%3A%20green%3B%20%7D" />
```

You can create this in JavaScript simply by URL encoding your string of CSS and adding it the `HREF` attribute. Much simpler than all the quirks of `<style>` elements or directly accessing stylesheets.

```
var linkElement = this.document.createElement('link');
linkElement.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
linkElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
linkElement.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/css;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(myStringOfstyles));
```

This will work in IE 5.5 upwards

The solution you have marked will work but this solution requires fewer dom operations and only a single element.

Comment: `let linkElement: HTMLLinkElement = this.document.createElement('link');` will work in IE 5.5, you say?

Comment: @JānisElmeris if you use javascript with the syntax used by the ie it will. createElement and setAttribute are not new methods.

Comment: @BogdanM., well, I just expect code described as "this will work in ..." to actually already have the proper syntax.

Comment: `let linkElement: HTMLLinkElement = ...` - what's this syntax called?

Comment: Sorry, that's a Typescript type. It shouldn't really be in there.

Comment: Aren't you missing the part where you append it to `<head>`?

Comment: I would add it to the head in the same way elements are added in the question. It doesn't bear repeating.

Comment: it is necessary add element to the head: `document.head.appendChild(linkElement)`

Answer (score 43):

**Edit**: As Atspulgs comment suggest, you can achieve the same without jQuery using the [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
document.head.innerHTML += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css"/>';
```

Older answer below.

---

You could use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) library to select your head element and append HTML to it, in a manner like:

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css" />');
```

You can find a complete tutorial for this problem [here](http://www.rickardnilsson.net/post/2008/08/02/Applying-stylesheets-dynamically-with-jQuery.aspx)

Comment: Again, this method loads a new file, which Yuri wanted to avoid. Also, loading the entire jQuery library for something as simple as this is rather silly.

Comment: without jQuery:
document.querySelector('head').innerHTML += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css"/>';

Comment: `document.head`, is the `head` element!

Answer (score 27):

If you don't want to rely on a javascript library, you can use `document.write()` to spit out the required css, wrapped in `style` tags, straight into the document `head`:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<style>body { background-color:#000 }</style>");
  </script>
  # other stuff..
</head>
```

This way you avoid firing an extra HTTP request.

There are other solutions that have been suggested / added / removed, but I don't see any point in overcomplicating something that already works fine cross-browser. Good luck!

http://jsbin.com/oqede3/edit

Comment: That's fine until you want to add a CSS rule after the document has rendered.

Comment: Good thing OP doesn't have that requirement then! Your solution covers that, but imho it's totally overkill for non-js/lightbox css degradation as this.

Comment: One thing to note: `document.write` doesn't work in real XHTML documents, but that's unlikely to be a problem since hardly anyone really uses XHTML.

Comment: it's interesting that it works but having style in the body looks a bit hacky :) p.s. you can put the document.write in the head section of the site and it seems to work fine.

Comment: My bad - it doesn't fire when the `script` is nested inside `style` tags, but you can drop it straight into the head :)

Comment: @Jeriko you can edit the answer so that you don't confuse people

Comment: Ewww... Since several issues I've had with `document.write` destroying my entire page, I make a point to avoid it and stick to `document.getElementById(...).innerHTML = `. There's never a need for `document.write`.

Comment: Updated my answer to include `getElementById`. I don't like `document.write` either, but it's often a lot simpler to explain, as you can see.

Comment: @steven_desu I added a non document.write solution in my question. plus innerHTML ain't that much better :) @Jeriko I really don't like your dynamic styles approach, why not use the edited roryf solution? MUCH more elegant IMO. p.s. I marked your's as best because it was the simplest and working solution to my incomplete question.

Comment: I tend to prefer solutions that are most likely to work cross-browser. It seems @roryf's answer has IE issues. As far as I'm concerned, when you're already doing something quick and dirty (adding css rules on the fly), it's whatever gets the job done properly :P

Comment: @Jeriko: assigning to the `innerHTML` property of a `<style>` element doesn't work in IE 6-8 (not sure about 9). Stick to the `document.write` solution and don't worry about @steven_desu's comment: there are some tasks for which only `document.write` will do.

Comment: @steven_desu: `document.write` will only destroy your entire page if you use it incorrectly (e.g. after the page has rendered). There's no danger if you know what you're doing. And as this very example proves, there sometimes is a need for `document.write`.

Comment: @jeriko yea, I agree with Tim Down, consider removing the second example, or make it into what I posted in the question which is roryf's answer that works in IE.

Comment: Thanks Tim and Yuri - seems we are in agreeance.. I never understood why things had to be overcomplicated when a simple solution works, and invariably works better :) I've removed the other solution.

Comment: I would avoid document.write as much as possible.

Comment: I would avoid document.write() because it makes web page render 10 times slower according to Google PageSpeed Insight

Answer (score 14):

A simple non-jQuery solution, albeit with a bit of a hack for IE:

```
var css = ".lightbox { width: 400px; height: 400px; border: 1px solid #333}";

var htmlDiv = document.createElement('div');
htmlDiv.innerHTML = '<p>foo</p><style>' + css + '</style>';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(htmlDiv.childNodes[1]);
```

It seems IE does not allow setting `innerText`, `innerHTML` or using `appendChild` on `style` elements. Here is a [bug report](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/IE_wont_allow_documentcreateElementstyle.html) which demonstrates this, although I think it identifies the problem incorrectly. The workaround above is from the comments on the bug report and has been tested in IE6 and IE9.

Whether you use this, document.write or a more complex solution will really depend on your situation.

Comment: Doesn't work in IE. Certainly not 6 or 7, don't have 8 available to test right now. IE doesn't like `document.createElement('style')`.

Comment: @Tim works for me in IE6 and 9, since your solution has the exact same line perhaps you can explain further

Comment: @roryf: Oh, yes, you're right, sorry. Foolishly I made the elementary mistake of believing the line number in IE's error. The error's actually in `styleElement.innerHTML = css;`. Certainly fails in IE 7, retesting in IE 6 now (waiting for VM to come alive).

Comment: @Tim thanks, I suspected that might be a problem, shame on me for not testing properly!

Comment: http://www.phpied.com/dynamic-script-and-style-elements-in-ie/ a link that i found thanks to the ie error that it gave me :)

Comment: if this worked cross-browser and maybe even ie5, then this would be the best answer ever.

Comment: I couldn't leave this alone so did a bit of research and found a workaround for IE, this should now work cross-browser

Comment: @roryf: So you have. Eugh. `<style>` element is not a valid descendant of a `<div>` element, so it may be possible that future, more standards-compliant IEs may not allow this. But still, inventively horrible. Well done :)

Comment: @Tim good point, wonder if creating a `<head>` element would work... Anyway, 'eugh' is a pretty accurate description ;-)

Answer (score 14):

Here's a simple way.

```
/**
 * Add css to the document
 * @param {string} css
 */
function addCssToDocument(css){
  var style = document.createElement('style')
  style.innerText = css
  document.head.appendChild(style)
}
```

Comment: I would use [`style.textContent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35213639/8804293)

Answer (score 10):

Here's a function that will dynamically create a CSS rule in all major browsers.  `createCssRule` takes a selector (e.g. "p.purpleText"), a rule (e.g. "color: purple;") and optionally a `Document` (the current document is used by default):

```
var addRule;

if (typeof document.styleSheets != "undefined" && document.styleSheets) {
    addRule = function(selector, rule) {
        var styleSheets = document.styleSheets, styleSheet;
        if (styleSheets && styleSheets.length) {
            styleSheet = styleSheets[styleSheets.length - 1];
            if (styleSheet.addRule) {
                styleSheet.addRule(selector, rule)
            } else if (typeof styleSheet.cssText == "string") {
                styleSheet.cssText = selector + " {" + rule + "}";
            } else if (styleSheet.insertRule && styleSheet.cssRules) {
                styleSheet.insertRule(selector + " {" + rule + "}", styleSheet.cssRules.length);
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    addRule = function(selector, rule, el, doc) {
        el.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(selector + " {" + rule + "}"));
    };
}

function createCssRule(selector, rule, doc) {
    doc = doc || document;
    var head = doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    if (head && addRule) {
        var styleEl = doc.createElement("style");
        styleEl.type = "text/css";
        styleEl.media = "screen";
        head.appendChild(styleEl);
        addRule(selector, rule, styleEl, doc);
        styleEl = null;
    }
};

createCssRule("body", "background-color: purple;");
```

Comment: Very thorough answer, and I believe it will come in handy, but it will be painstaking to take a simple css stylesheet and convert it to this.

Answer (score 2):

In one call:

```
document.head.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement("style"), {textContent: `
    select, button, input, details, summary { cursor: pointer }
    input { padding: 0.5rem }
    button, select  { margin: 0.5rem }
    @media (max-width:640px) { button  { width: 100% } i {display: block } }
  `
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Shortest One liner**:

```
const addCSS = css => document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("style")).innerHTML = css;

// Usage:
addCSS("body{background:red}");
```

Comment: Does it work cross browser?

Comment: It should support all browsers except old IE. I'd appreciate if someone can tell what is the oldest IE version supported.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, quite similar to all solution but appends only once the script to the `head`:

```
export const injectHeadCss = () => {
  let style: HTMLStyleElement | null = document.head.querySelector('style[my-style]');

  if (style !== null) {
    return;
  }

  style = document.createElement('style');
  style.setAttribute('my-style', '');
  style.innerHTML = `
    .class1 {
      background: pink;
    }

    .class2 {
      background: purple;
    }
  `;

  document.head.append(style);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Maximizing compatibility, working for most things made 2009-2022 and likely beyond. This solution is intentionally not made with ES6 etc; using an arrow function, let-variable, append (2014) etc.

This short version adds styling to the head-section of a web page and can also be done via the DOM to access the head-section to maximize compatibility further - since querySelector wasn't widely adapted until 2009.

Note that innerHTML / write nowadays isn't recommended for production.

Just copy+paste it into the console to try it out and a page like this gets some nice additions;

```
function ahsf(styling){ document.querySelector('head').innerHTML+="<style>"+ styling +"</style>";}
//Called with
ahsf(" * { border: 1px dashed #f09 !important; } ");
```