# Put CSS in header with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have to put CSS (block in the header) with Javascript or JQuery in the header of the current page.
The css is in text format, like this (it comes from a server):

```
label { font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; display: block; }
input { padding: 3px 5px; width: 250px; margin: 0 0 10px; }
input[type="file"] { padding-left: 0; }
input[type="submit"] { width: auto; }
```

I want to put this CSS in the header block, with JavaScript like this:

```
<meta name="author" content="" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/global.css" />
<style type="text/css">
    label { font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; display: block; }
    input { padding: 3px 5px; width: 250px; margin: 0 0 10px; }
    input[type="file"] { padding-left: 0; }
    input[type="submit"] { width: auto; }
</style>
</head>
```

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
 $('<style type="text/css"> ' + myCSS + '</style>').appendTo('head');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery to do this. 
Do something like this:

```
$("head").append("<style type=\"text/css\">" + {your content} + "</style>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you should be able to do an `append`

`$('head').append(' //stick the whole thing here ');`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, checkout this tutorial so you can understand how it's done: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Howto_Dynamically_Insert_Javascript_And_CSS

Edit: If you don't need to run the script in the body, there is a similar question here: [Add CSS to <head> with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922139/add-css-to-head-with-javascript)

```
function addcss(css){
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var styleElement = document.createElement('style');
    styleElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    if (styleElement.styleSheet) {   // IE
        styleElement.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } else {                // the world
        styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }
    head.appendChild(styleElement);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this lib may help:

https://github.com/cssobj/cssobj

It's render CSSOM from JS into `<head>`, and you can change rules directly from JS Object.

DEMO: https://cssobj.github.io/cssobj-demo/

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var css = document.createElement('style');
 css.type = 'text/css';

 var styles = 'your_server_response_css_rules';

 if (css.styleSheet)
     css.styleSheet.cssText = styles;
 else 
     css.appendChild(document.createTextNode(styles));

 document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
</script>
```