# How to call CSS animation manually with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, uiwebview

I'm using a UIWebView with CSS animations, which animates the main body when it loads from alpha 0 to 1:

```
 NSString *HTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                      "<head> \n"
                      "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                      "@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {from {opacity: 0;-webkit-transition: opacity;}to {opacity: 1;}} \n"
                      "body {\n"
                      "-webkit-animation-name:fadeIn;\n"
                      "-webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;\n"
                       ...
```

My question is, how would I call this animation manually using Javascript so that at any time, if I call the JS, the view animates from 0 to 1 (rather than just animating on load)? Or is this not possible with CSS?

Basically I want to do this:

```
[mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"/*animate*/"];
```

Comment: I think that your problem is more a "how can I call CSS in Javascript"'s problem. IMHO, I would either [add the CSS with a Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922139/add-css-to-head-with-javascript) function that would append the CSS content in the head, or use a Javascript framework (like jQuery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding the transition to the body and adding a class later that changes the property with a transition attached via jQuery or any other library to the body at your time of choosing.  A simple example of this is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fwteu/4/

And an example that animates the opacity from a callback to show the body:

http://jsfiddle.net/tCfb5/

Comment: I tried putting opacity: 0 in `white`, but then it doesn't animate anymore. Why's that?

Comment: Because you haven't set a transition on opacity.  See the second example there.

Comment: Now how would I add this with a Javascript string?

Answer (score 0):

You would just set `opacity: 0` in the normal CSS (through class or whatever) and then set `domObject.style.opacity = 1` in the JavaScript you run on load. Animation happens any time the property changes, so you just have to change the property when you want the animation to happen.

Comment: I'm doing this, but nothing is happening: `[mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"main\").style.opacity = 1"];`

Comment: Ok I'm using document.body.style.opacity = 1.0, it works, but it doesn't animate..