# Apply CSS dynamically with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, encapsulation, styling, web-component

**What is a good way to apply styling dynamically (i.e. the value of styles are created at runtime) to HTML elements with JavaScript?**

I'm looking for a way to package a JavaScript widget (JS, CSS and markup) in a single component (basically, an object). The idea would be for the component to encapsulate styling (so users have a nice API to modify it instead of a more tightly coupled approach of modifying the CSS directly and having changes applied indirectly). The problem is that a single API call might imply changes to several styling elements.

The way I would do it is to construct the CSS and set the`style` atrribute to the proper elements (most likely using the ID to avoid applying changes to other areas of the markup). Is this a good solution? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I would create css rules with JS, the inline style solution imply that you have to change all styles attributes when you need to make a change for a set of elements.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Using Jquery**

Use the css() function to apply style to existing elements where you pass an object containing styles :

```
var styles = {
  backgroundColor : "#ddd",
  fontWeight: ""
};
$("#myId").css(styles);
```

You can also apply one style at the time with :

```
$("#myId").css("border-color", "#FFFFFF");
```

**Vanilla JS :**

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("#myId");
myDiv.setAttribute("style", "border-color:#FFFFFF;");
```

**With Css :**

You can also use a separate css file containing the different styles needed inside classes, and depending on the context you add or remove those classes to your elements.

in your css file you can have classes like

```
.myClass {
    background-color: red;
}

.myOtherClass {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Again using jquery, to add or remove a class to an element, you can use

```
$("#myDiv").addClass('myClass');
```

or

```
$("#myDiv").removeClass('myClass');
```

Again, you can also do the same with vanilla JS:

```
document.getElementById("#myId").classList.add('myClass')
```

or

```
document.getElementById("#myId").classList.remove('myClass')
```

I think this is a cleaner way as it separates your style from your logic. But if the values of your css depends from what is returned by the server, this solution might be difficult to apply.

Comment: Cool, I like this. However, having predefined CSS is something I'd like to avoid, as it'd require users to know how the widget is structured internally, which breaks encapsulation. Thanks!

Comment: Are there any equivalent methods in vanila js for addClass and removeClass?

Comment: Ok. I found the answer to my question here. 
https://www.developeracademy.io/blog/add-remove-css-classes-using-javascript/

Answer (score 8):

The way I would do it is to construct the CSS and set the style attribute to the proper elements. For example:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute("style", "color: blue, margin-top:5px");
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

This code will create a new div element with the style `color: blue, margin-top:5px` and append it to the page.

Comment: "The way I would do it is to construct the CSS and set the style atrribute to the proper elements "

Comment: I would rather use the `style` property of the DOM Element instead of the `setAttribute()`, something like: `div.style = 'color: blue, margin-top:5px'`

Comment: Aren't these all the same?

Comment: OP is about "Is this a good solution? Is there a better way to do it?" not how  to add inline style.

Comment: This is the best way to do it, you can of course write CSS and place it into your head dynamically `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922139/add-css-to-head-with-javascript` then add classes to the element but there is no point in over complicating what is a simple problem. Easy to read and easy to change.

Comment: Yeah, like I said in the question, this sounds like the best. However, I don't understand the distinction of setting the DOM element's `style` property vs atrribute. How does that impact the solution? If it merits asking a new question, let me know and I'll get to it.

Comment: Mozilla states "Setting style Note that styles should NOT be set by assigning a string directly to the style property (as in elt.style = "color: blue;" ), since it is considered read-only because the style attribute returns a CSSStyleDeclaration object which is also read-only." -https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Comment: No answer or comment so far mentions how to add a style in plain JS without modifying existing styles of the element. Though the question asks only about setting, useful for those who end up here looking for how to add. @DeanMeehan has quoted the doc mentioning how not to do it. Next line says how to do it: **Instead, styles can be set by assigning values to the properties of `style`. For adding specific styles to an element without altering other style values, it is preferred to use the individual properties of `style` (as in `elt.style.color = '...'`) as using `elt.style.cssText = '...'`**

Answer (score 7):

Using **Vanilla JS** you could do something like this.

If you want to add a **CSS class** named **animate** to an element with Id **circle**, do it like this.

```
var circle = document.getElementById("circle");
circle.classList.add('animate');
```

You can remove the class like this.

```
circle.classList.remove('animate');
```

Comment: keep in mind poor IE support. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: the proper answer now that IE is EOL

Answer (score 1):

Since you have also asked if there is a better way and you building a component, a better way i would recommend is for you to build such a component with frontend javascript framework because they make dynamically styles very easy out of the box
take an example of Vuejs, Reactjs

```
`      
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-jss'
const Circle = styled('div')({
  position: 'absolute',
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  borderRadius: '50%',
  background: (props) => (
    /* Generates a random or based on props color */
  ),
  transform: (props) => (
    /* Generates a random or based on props transform for  positioning */
  )
})
class Demo extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.tick()
  }
  tick = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.setState({/* Some new state */}, this.tick)
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {[...Array(amount)].map(() => <Circle />)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be misinterpreting your question, but it sounds like you are asking for a simple architectural pattern. You want something that makes it easier for someone who is using your widget to change it to their specifications?

If this is the case, then I do not know of any special pattern to do this without using CSS.

I can tell you that the "widgets" that I have found easiest to use do have separate CSS files. I have found it fairly straightforward to modify them to my needs. I think this is because the structure of using CSS with HTML and Javascript is already a nice, simple pattern. I don't know of there is anything better, especially considering that people are already very familiar with the HTML/CSS relationship.

Comment: The question goes along the lines of creating components with JS that can be independent of each other. While what you say about HTML and CSS being standard is absolutely true, this is more about packaging things in a way that enhances cohesion and reduces coupling. Packaged like this, users of the widget need not know what styling is done in order to construct the widget, which has the added benefit of not requiring them to know more than a single API to interact with it.

Comment: I think you want to use .attr('style', '...') or .css('width, etc', '0px,etc..") then.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onscroll = function(){workOnScroll()};
function workOnScroll() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
      var ul = document.getElementById("ulID");
      ul.setAttribute("style", "position: sticky;top: 150px;");
  } else {
      var ul = document.getElementById("ulID");
      ul.setAttribute("style", "position: relative;top: 0px;");
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).