# How to apply css in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a few buttons that were made though a loop in javasript.

```
    var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i=0; i < 9 ; i++){ 
        var row = document.createElement("tr") 
        for (var j=0; j < 9 ; j++){ 
                var elem = document.createElement('input');
                elem.class = 'gumb';
                elem.style.color = 'purple';
                elem.type = 'button';
                elem.id = 'r'+i+'s'+j;
                elem.value = '';
                elem.innerHTML = elem.value; 
                docFrag.appendChild(elem); 
            } 
        document.body.appendChild(docFrag); 
        document.body.appendChild(row); 
    }
```

And I want to apply css to them, but nothing seems to work. I tried it using `elem.style` and through a special style.css file using the button's class but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: I hope this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/35630641/10553411

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usage of `elem.class` is wrong. 
Following usages are valid:

- `elem.classList.add('gumb')`
- `elem.className = 'gumb'`
- `elem.setAttribute('class', 'gumb')`

Answer (score 3):

You need to change `elem.class` to `elem.className`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp

`class` is a reserved word in a lot of languages, so you'll find it might have an alternative name, such as `className`

Answer (score 1):

You need use  `elem.className = 'gumb';` also should set `value` for button to have purple color

```js
   var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i=0; i < 9 ; i++){ 
        var row = document.createElement("tr") 
        for (var j=0; j < 9 ; j++){ 
                var elem = document.createElement('input');
                elem.className = 'gumb';
                
                elem.style.color = 'purple';
                elem.type = 'button';
                elem.id = 'r'+i+'s'+j;
                elem.value = 'A';
                elem.innerHTML = elem.value; 
                docFrag.appendChild(elem); 
            } 
        document.body.appendChild(docFrag); 
        document.body.appendChild(row); 
    }
```

```css
.gumb{
background-color:"#fff";
}
```