# How can I select elements using classes on different elements with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I want to select the Table like it is done at the moment. Unfortunately on another page i also have a table that should not be affected.
At the moment i select by the class "mb-bhi-closed" which has to stay to only affect the active line in the table.
But i would also like to before select to only to affect the footer with the elementor selector for footers "elementor-location-footer".
How can i stack these? The current code is following:

```
$is_opened = MBHIPRO()->is_open('ThaiMama Horgen');

if($is_opened){
   add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_color_openingtimes_green' );
}

function custom_color_openingtimes_green(){
    ?>
          <script>
                 var simple = document.getElementsByClassName("mbhi-is-current");
                 for (i = 0; i < simple.length; i++) {
                   simple[i].style.color="green";
                 }
         </script>
<?php
    
}
```

Has somebody got an idea?

EDIT 1:
The table I want to modify is always in the footer, yes. The one time it also appears NOT in the footer, i also DONT want it to be adjusted. So the "elementor-location-footer" class is in a div many parents above. Here you got a screenshot for visualization: https://screencast.com/t/59ZENnle4/
@isherwood: Thanks for the Input, as i'm new to active participation in StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks, but that information belongs in your question, not down here.

Comment: Usually WP themes add the page name to the `body` class with a PHP function that can be leveraged for per-page CSS. Does your theme do this? Then you could use CSS to only target the page with the table to change

Comment: @wouch: it should be applied to the footer on all pages...
Is there no way to just do cascading like in CSS? .footer .table?

Comment: Okay, then yes I would use `.elementor-location-footer table.mabel-bhi-businesshours` which should only target that table when in the footer

Comment: @wouch That was exactly my question, how do i apply a CSS selector like this in JS?

Comment: I recommend styling via CSS, but you can do it a few ways via JS. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630641/apply-css-dynamically-with-javascript) offers a few options that would work