# Applying CSS in JavaScript indirectly

Tags: javascript, css

When you write real CSS you could do

```
.blue { color: blue; }
```

and if you added the class "blue" to an element after loading, it would turn blue.

In JavaScript you would have to do something like

```
var blue = document.getElementsByClassName('blue');
for (var i = 0; i < blue.length; i++)
     blue[i].style.setProperty('color', 'blue');
```

The problem with the JavaScript version is if you did

```
document.getElementById('someId').className += " blue";
```

it would have the class blue, but it would not turn blue.
Is there any way (preferably simple) to add the style to the selector rather then directly to the elements with that selector?

Comment: I don't understand your dislike towards css?  CSS is a great tool for separating style and logic (which is Javascript).  Just make the class in css and add it with javascript!

Comment: its not object oriented. Splitting the data in two files makes it less encapsulated. Seperate style and logic within your javascript file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript).  You can add a `<style>` element via JavaScript.

Comment: That could get messy very easily though. I thought about that, and it would take a very thoroughly thought out algorithm to make sure properties/selectors aren't duplicated. I'm going to try it but I have no idea what the outcome will be. Wish me luck. xD

Comment: It all depends on the context you're using it; I assumed it was your own Web page so you could know what classes were defined.  You could add a unique ID or the time to the class name, if you were really worried about it working in any web page.

Answer (score 2):

The most common way is defining  `.blue { color:blue; }` in the CSS **beforehand**, then adding the class to the element via JS. That way styles are in the CSS and only class names are in the JS, making it more flexible instead of hardcoding dozens of css keys/values in the JS.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML

```
<div id="test">This will turn blue</div>
<button onclick="addClass()" >add Class </button>
```

The Javascript

```
function addClass(){
    document.getElementById('test').className += 'blue';
}
```

The CSS

```
.blue{
     color:blue;
}
```

This works in FF IE7 and Chrome. Perhaps there is something else going on in your code which is stopping this from working.

Comment: People aren't getting that I don't want to use CSS. I want to figure out how to do that in PURE JavaScript. Nothing else, but HTML.