# Changing URL when users visit with jQuery

Tags: jquery, url

I have to make this happen using jQuery...

When users visit any page on my website (coming from another site) this has to occurs (the pathname varies)

http://www.mywebsite.com/pathname/

become

http://www.mywebsite.com/#!/pathname

I need help with the syntax.

Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Just FYI, the jQuery Address plugin is a good tool to do this kind of job: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Comment: I'm using it... it makes all my internal links go from http://www.mywebsite.com/pathname/ to http://www.mywebsite.com/#!/pathname but i don't know if I can and how to set it up to make this behaviour when links are coming from the outside of the site.

Comment: You might want to look into something like Apache's `mod_redirect` or `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pieces = location.href.split('/');
    if (pieces[3].indexOf('#!') !== 0) {
        if (location.href.indexOf('#!') != -1) {
            pieces = location.href.replace('#!','').split('/');
        }
        pieces[3] = '#!/'+pieces[3];
        location.href = pieces.join('/');
    }
});
```

To hide content:

```
// I don't know you actually need this, since it may hide content
// in some cases when the redirect may not work, which might give
// the user a blank white page.
// Alternatively, you could use CSS as Ben notes, although you would
// only need display: none on the body tag.
$('body').ready(function(){$(this).hide();});

// Note, this is NOT in a handler.
var pieces = location.href.split('/');
if (pieces[3].indexOf('#!') !== 0) {
    if (location.href.indexOf('#!') != -1) {
        pieces = location.href.replace('#!','').split('/');
    }
    pieces[3] = '#!/'+pieces[3];
    location.href = pieces.join('/');
}
```

Demo: http://jfcoder.com/test/redirect.html

Comment: Nice solution! It relies on there being two slashes in the URL, but that's a safe assumption to make.

Comment: Thank you it works! I'm currious, is there a way to make sure it works even if the url is http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/pathname/ ? Where the site is actually hosted in blog directory

Comment: You would change the `pieces[]` number to be equal to how many `/`'s over from the left you need to go. If it's one level, like `http://mywebsite.com/blog/#!/pathname`, you would need to use `pieces[4]`, since there are four `/`'s.

Comment: Oh, one problem, I see the content of http://www.mywebsite.com/pathname/ before it redirects to http://www.mywebsite.com/#!/pathname/. Is it because it's using a $(document).ready(); because I tried using $(window).load(); and I still see the content of the first page. Is there a work around?

Comment: If this is in the head you could add a style tag. Paste this inside the if statement and use the load handler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript/524721#524721 Change the CSS to `body { background-color: white; } body * { display: none; }`. Also change ready to load. This should hopefully work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this using jQuery. You can just use `window.location.href = "new url";`

However if you insist...

```
var url = $(location).attr("href");
var path = url.substring(url.indexOf("com")+3);
var newurl = "http://www.mywebsite/#!" + path;
$(location).attr("href",newurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (untested):

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var hostname = window.location.hostname;
var newPath = pathname.replace(pathname, "#!" + pathname);
window.location.href = hostname + pathname;
```

Answer (score 0):

for what it's worth

```
var blah = document.referrer.substr(document.referrer.indexOf("/")+2);
if(blah.substr(0,blah.indexOf("/")) != location.host) location.href = (location.host + "/#!" + location.pathname);
```