# unexpected call to method or property access

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, createelement

If you try to add style declarations in the head of a document, IE borks at the name 'style' - "unexpected call to method or property access".

I guess its getting confused between the head element  and the object property .style?

```
var t = document.createElement("style")
t.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
t.setAttribute("media", "screen");
var temp_text = document.createTextNode(v + " {visibility:hidden}");
t.appendChild(temp_text)
```

Where **v** is id of a flash object.

Comment: Can you post some example code?

Comment: Please be clear in explaining your problems and just paste the code snippet wer u r getting trouble

Comment: Duplicated question. See answer: [How to create a <style> tag with Javascript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help: http://www.phpied.com/dynamic-script-and-style-elements-in-ie/

Answer (score 1):

For IE U have do like this

```
    var t = document.createElement("style")
    t.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    t.setAttribute("media", "screen");
    if(t.styleSheet)
        t.styleSheet.cssText = v + " {visibility:hidden}" ;
    else
    {
        var temp_text = document.createTextNode(v + " {visibility:hidden}");
        t.appendChild(temp_text)
    }
```

This would help you