# Javascript: Can i dynamically create a CSSStyleSheet object and insert it?

Tags: javascript, dom

I know `document.styleSheets` which consists of all valid style sheets in a page. I want to know whether i can create a new one and append it to present list via javascript.

I have tried `document.styleSheets[0].constructor`, `document.styleSheets[0].__proto__.constructor`, `new CSSStyleSheet`, `CSSStyleSheet()`, all what i get from Chrome is `TypeError: Illegal constructor`. `CSSStyleSheet.constructor()` returned a pure object but i expect a CSSStyleSheet object.

**I know i can create a link/style element and append it, then modify it. What i want to know is that, can i create such object directly with javascript?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript

Comment: simply create a new `style` element, and append it. a new `CSSStyleSheet` will be created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the only approach that comes close to what you're asking for is the **IE-only** [`document.createStyleSheet([url] [,index])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method which you can use to create up to 31<sup>*</sup> `styleSheet` objects (after which you'll still need to manually create `style` elements and append them to `document`).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript/524798#524798) shows how you can define the `createStyleSheet()` method for non-IE browsers but as you'd expect it does so by appending `link`/`style` elements (which for some reason you're trying to avoid).

---

<sup>*</sup> IE 6 to 9 is limited to 31 imported stylesheets [due to 5-bit field used for storing sheet IDs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/14/internet-explorer-stylesheet-rule-selector-import-sheet-limit-maximum.aspx). In IE10 this limit has been raised to 4095.

Comment: _*Blink*_. IE still continues to impress me.

Answer (score 25):

There's [a brand new proposal](https://wicg.github.io/construct-stylesheets/) that makes it possible to directly call the `CSSStyleSheet` constructor. Doing what you want to looks like this:

```
// Construct the CSSStyleSheet
const stylesheet = new CSSStyleSheet();

// Add some CSS
stylesheet.replaceSync('body { background: #000 !important; }')
// OR stylesheet.replace, which returns a Promise instead

// Tell the document to adopt your new stylesheet.
// Note that this also works with Shadow Roots.
document.adoptedStyleSheets = [stylesheet];
```

Note that currently this only works on Chrome Canary, but hopefully other browsers will implement this feature soon.

Comment: Update: as of now supported in Chromium but not in Safari

Comment: Now (mid-2022) available [on most browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet#browser_compatibility); only Safari is still holding out. Now let's hope for a constructor for `CSSStyleRule` objects, to bring an end to 'injecting source code'.

Answer (score 22):

I know you said you didn't want to create an element, but that's genuinely the only way to do it. A few people have detailed this approach above, but i notice nobody covered off that `HTMLStyleElement` and `HTMLLinkElement` both have a neat [`sheet` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LinkStyle) to get direct access to their `CSSStyleSheet`:

```
var style = document.createElement("style");
document.head.appendChild(style); // must append before you can access sheet property
var sheet = style.sheet;

console.log(sheet instanceof CSSStyleSheet);
```

Much simpler than searching through `document.styleSheets`

Comment: Additionally you may set the style.disabled property to true if you don't want to have a visual impact on your current document.

Comment: hi for me in chrome style.sheet isn't defined

Comment: @bluejayke I just pasted the exact snippet above into the chrome console and it worked. You can't access `sheet` property of stylesheets coming from another domain btw, the same-origin policy applies

Comment: @WickyNilliams Yes you're right... I was adding style.type = "style/css", which isn't even a valid type, when I took it out / changed it to "text/css", it worked :)

Comment: Note that you cannot edit this sheet using `replace` and friends, as its not a constructed StyleSheet.

Comment: @paradox460 constructable stylesheets were not a thing when i wrote this 7 years ago :) `replace` does not have broad support (yet) anyway

Answer (score 7):

If you are trying to write the css inside of javascript, do this:

```
var s = document.createElement('style');
s.type = 'text/css';
s.innerText = 'body { background: #222; } /*... more css ..*/';
document.head.appendChild(s);
```

Whereas if you are trying to load a stylesheet from the server:

```
var s = document.createElement('link');
s.type = 'text/css';
s.rel = 'stylesheet';
s.href = '/url/to/css/file.css';
document.head.appendChild(s);
```

Comment: Sorry, but i have said i know this method. I'm wondering whether i can create this object directly with javascript or not.

Comment: Don't use `innerText`, it's not part of any standard and doesn't have full browser compatibility.  Use `s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(styles))` for full compat.

Comment: @regality I want to create this object like `new CSSStyleSheet`, your method just pollutes DOM.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can. The `document.styleSheets` cannot be modified directly, but you can add an entry by adding a new style tag to your document:

```
// Create the style element
var elem = $('<style id="lwuiStyle"></style>');
$('head').append(elem);

// Find its CSSStyleSheet entry in document.styleSheets
var yourSheet = null;
for (var sheet of document.styleSheets) {
    if (sheet.ownerNode == elem[0]) {
        yourSheet = sheet;
        break;
    }
}

// Test it by changing the background colour
yourSheet.insertRule('body {background-color: #fa0}', yourSheet.cssRules.length);
```

If you run Firefox, you can directly test this in Scratchpad: Copy the code, press `Shift+F4`, paste it, and run the code with `Ctrl+L`. Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this:

```
var myCSSStyleSheetIbj = Object.create(document.styleSheets[0])
```

Assuming that document.styleSheets[0] is a CSSStyleSheet Object,
Actually if you replace document.styleSheets[0] with any CSSStyleSheet it would work.

Comment: To create an *empty* object, you might rather want to use  `Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(document.styleSheets[0]))` here – but adding the object does not seem to be allowed.

Comment: Great, but once I create it, how do I insert it into my document?

Answer (score 2):

`Object.create(CSSStyleSheet.prototype)`

gives you back an empty instance of CSSStyleSheet. In other words, it does exactly what you would expect `new CSSStyleSheet` to do.

`Object.create` is available in any browser with ECMAScript 5 support. Find a compatibility table [here](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/).

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate? Instead of posting one line of rather cryptic code?

Comment: It's the answer to the question and so any comment would have been unnecessary in my eyes. The statement returns a new instance of CSSStyleSheet and that's it.

Comment: Great, now I have a new object, how do I insert it into my document?

Comment: While this looks like a good Idea, the resulting object is not usable as expected and throws an error - at least in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Safari support CSSStyleSheet since 16.4 : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-16_4-release-notes#CSS-API