# Change :hover CSS properties with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dhtml

How can JavaScript change CSS `:hover` properties?

For example:

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hover 1</td>
    <td>Hover 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table td:hover {
background:#ff0000;
}
```

How can the `td :hover` properties be modified to, say, `background:#00ff00`, with JavaScript? I know I could access the style background property using JavaScript with:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("td").style.background="#00ff00";
```

But I don't know of a `.style` JavaScript equivalent for `:hover`.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Pseudo classes like `:hover` never refer to an element, but to any element that satisfies the conditions of the stylesheet rule. You need to *edit the stylesheet rule*, *append a new rule*, or add a new stylesheet that includes the new `:hover` rule.

```
var css = 'table td:hover{ background-color: #00ff00 }';
var style = document.createElement('style');

if (style.styleSheet) {
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

Comment: If you're taking this route, [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/changess.html) may help in the future as well.

Comment: If looking to append the stylesheet, would it not be `style.styleSheet.cssText += css;`?

Comment: @Andi No, because `style` variable in kennebec's answer is a new element created in the code and doesn't point to an existing `<style>` tag in the HTML.

Comment: Why is it unknown whether the new `style` element already has a styleSheet or not?

Comment: How would you find and edit a current stylesheet rule, to change it?   This shows adding a new rule, but what if there already is a rule, and it's just a value being changed?

Comment: @JGallardo what would be better variable names in your opinion?

Comment: your solution worked fine and this one did not:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209086/javascript-can-i-dynamically-create-a-cssstylesheet-object-and-insert-it  (Dabolus)  -- i will figure that one out in a different lifetime.

Answer (score 57):

You [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754546/can-i-disable-a-css-hover-effect-via-javascript) change or alter the actual `:hover` selector through Javascript. You can, however, use [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseenter) to change the style, and revert back on [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseleave) (thanks, @Bryan).

Comment: There really is NO way to change the :hover selector with JavaScript?

Comment: Note that you are also going to need to bind [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseleave) in order to reverse the effects.

Comment: I've been using this on past projects and even tried the accepted answer recently, but this one always prevails when it comes to using hover/active elements with colored buttons. Just want to say thanks for posting this as an option.

Answer (score 29):

Pretty old question so I figured I'll add a more modern answer. Now that CSS variables are widely supported they can be used to achieve this without the need for JS events or `!important`.

Taking the OP's example:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hover 1</td>
    <td>Hover 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

We can now do this in the CSS:

```css
table td:hover {
  // fallback in case we need to support older/non-supported browsers (IE, Opera mini)
  background: #ff0000;
  background: var(--td-background-color);
}
```

And add the hover state using javascript like so:

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
tds.forEach((td) => {
  td.style.setProperty('--td-background-color', '#00ff00');
});
```

Here's a working example https://codepen.io/ybentz/pen/RwPoeqb

Comment: so you first define a css var and then change the var in js?

Comment: Yes! There's still no way on JS to target the `:hover` state but CSS variables allows you to "bypass" it by changing the value of the variable via JS while the CSS code doesn't change.

Comment: This is def the best answer now! Worked super for me

Answer (score 16):

What you can do is change the class of your object and define two classes with different hover properties. For example:

```
.stategood_enabled:hover  { background-color:green}
.stategood_enabled        { background-color:black}
.stategood_disabled:hover { background-color:red}
.stategood_disabled       { background-color:black}
```

And this I found on:
[Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

```
function changeClass(object,oldClass,newClass)
{
    // remove:
    //object.className = object.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)oldClass(?!\S)/g , '' );
    // replace:
    var regExp = new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)' + oldClass + '(?!\\S)', 'g');
    object.className = object.className.replace( regExp , newClass );
    // add
    //object.className += " "+newClass;
}

changeClass(myInput.submit,"stategood_disabled"," stategood_enabled");
```

Answer (score 16):

Sorry to find this page 7 years too late, but here is a much simpler way to solve this problem (changing hover styles arbitrarily):

HTML:

```
<button id=Button>Button Title</button>
```

CSS:

```
.HoverClass1:hover {color: blue !important; background-color: green !important;}
.HoverClass2:hover {color: red !important; background-color: yellow !important;}
```

JavaScript:

```
var Button=document.getElementById('Button');
/* Clear all previous hover classes */
Button.classList.remove('HoverClass1','HoverClass2');
/* Set the desired hover class */
Button.classList.add('HoverClass1');
```

Comment: This is only for one button right ? What if i want to add this effect to all the buttons

Comment: JavaScript provides several ways to handle multiple operations, including using arrays.

Answer (score 13):

If it fits your purpose you can add the hover functionality without using css and using the `onmouseover` event in javascript

Here is a code snippet

```
<div id="mydiv">foo</div>

<script>
document.getElementById("mydiv").onmouseover = function() 
{
    this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
</script>
```

Comment: This will persist the new style and won't go back to its previous one!

Comment: @Yahya - You can revert this color back on mouse out event.

Comment: Mouse events are not reliable, as people can switch tabs/applications without moving the mouse

Answer (score 12):

You can use mouse events to control like hover.
For example, the following code is making visible when you hover that element.

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
foo.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
   foo.style.display="block";
})
foo.addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
   foo.style.display="none";
})
```

Comment: You better use this.style.display="block"; | this.style.display="none";

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend to replace all `:hover` properties to `:active` when you detect that device supports touch. Just call this function when you do so as `touch()`

```
   function touch() {
      if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
        for (var sheetI = document.styleSheets.length - 1; sheetI >= 0; sheetI--) {
          var sheet = document.styleSheets[sheetI];
          if (sheet.cssRules) {
            for (var ruleI = sheet.cssRules.length - 1; ruleI >= 0; ruleI--) {
              var rule = sheet.cssRules[ruleI];

              if (rule.selectorText) {
                rule.selectorText = rule.selectorText.replace(':hover', ':active');
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not actually adding the CSS to the cell, but gives the same effect.  While providing the same result as others above, this version is a little more intuitive to me, but I'm a novice, so take it for what it's worth:

```
$(".hoverCell").bind('mouseover', function() {
    var old_color = $(this).css("background-color");
    $(this)[0].style.backgroundColor = '#ffff00';

    $(".hoverCell").bind('mouseout', function () {
        $(this)[0].style.backgroundColor = old_color;
    });
});
```

This requires setting the Class for each of the cells you want to highlight to "hoverCell".

Answer (score 3):

You can make a CSS variable, and then change it in JS.

```css
:root {
  --variableName: (variableValue);
}
```

to change it in JS, I made these handy little functions:

```js
var cssVarGet = function(name) {
  return getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue(name);
};
```

and

```js
var cssVarSet = function(name, val) {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty(name, val);
};
```

You can make as many CSS variables as you want, and I haven't found any bugs in the functions;
After that, all you have to do is embed it in your CSS:

```css
table td:hover {
  background: var(--variableName);
}
```

And then bam, a solution that just requires some CSS and 2 JS functions!

Answer (score 2):

I had this need once and created a small library for, which maintains the CSS documents

https://github.com/terotests/css

With that you can state

```
css().bind("TD:hover", {
        "background" : "00ff00"
    });
```

It uses the techniques mentioned above and also tries to take care of the cross-browser issues. If there for some reason exists an old browser like IE9 it will limit the number of STYLE tags, because the older IE browser had this strange limit for number of STYLE tags available on the page.

Also, it limits the traffic to the tags by updating tags only periodically. There is also a limited support for creating animation classes.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a global var:

```
var td
```

Then select your guiena pig `<td>` getting it by its `id`, if you want to change all of them then

```
window.onload = function () {
  td = document.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
}
```

Make a function to be triggered and a loop to change all of your desired `td`'s

```
function trigger() {
    for(var x = 0; x < td.length; x++) { 
      td[x].className = "yournewclass"; 
    }
}
```

Go to your CSS Sheet:

```
.yournewclass:hover { background-color: #00ff00; }
```

And that is it, with this you are able to to make all your `<td>` tags get a `background-color: #00ff00;` when hovered by changing its css propriety directly (switching between css classes).

Comment: I just applied this model on my SoloLearn playrground website, check by yourself and see how it works: https://code.sololearn.com/WEtMpJ0mwFAD/#js

Answer (score 2):

For myself, I found the following option: from https://stackoverflow.com/a/70557483/18862444

```js
const el = document.getElementById('elementId');
el.style.setProperty('--focusHeight', newFocusHeight);
el.style.setProperty('--focusWidth', newFocusWidth);
```

```css
.my-class {
  --focusHeight: 32px;
  --focusWidth: 256px;
}

.my-class:focus {
  height: var(--focusHeight);
  width: var(--focusWidth);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had some same problems, used addEventListener for events "mousenter", "mouseleave":

```js
let DOMelement = document.querySelector('CSS selector for your HTML element');

// if you want to change e.g color: 
let origColorStyle = DOMelement.style.color;

DOMelement.addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => { event.target.style.color = "red" });

DOMelement.addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => { event.target.style.color = origColorStyle })
```

Or something else for style when cursor is above the DOMelement.
DOMElement can be chosen by various ways.

Comment: Sorry, did not think it over first. You should also add an other event, when mouse leaves, and if you want to revert back the orig stly, one way, to save it in a variable

Answer (score 1):

I was researching about hover, to be able to implement them in the button label and make the hover effect

```html
<button type="submit"
        style=" background-color:cornflowerblue; padding:7px; border-radius:6px"
        onmouseover="this.style.cssText ='background-color:#a8ff78; padding:7px; border-radius:6px;'"
        onmouseout="this.style.cssText='background-color:cornflowerblue; padding:7px; border-radius:6px'"
        @click="form1()">
        Login
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    const tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
    tds.forEach((td,index) => {
      td.addEventListener("mouseover", ()=>hover(index))
      td.addEventListener("mouseout", ()=>normal(index))
    });
    function hover(index){
      tds[index].style.background="red";
    }
    function normal(index){
      tds[index].style.background="yellow";
    }
```

Try this code it will work fine .

Comment: While this answer probably has a similar effect, it does not answer the OP's Q. The Q is how to change the property of the `:hover` pseudo class. Your code changes the background color of the "un-pseudoed" element.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class in css

```
.hover:hover {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

and then add it dynamically

```
const columns = document.querySelectorAll('table td');

for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
   columns[i].classList.add('hover');
}
```

But your css and js files should be connected in index.html

Answer (score -1):

If you use lightweight html ux lang, [check here an example](http://katecode.herokuapp.com/), write:

```
div root
 .onmouseover = ev => {root.style.backgroundColor='red'}
 .onmouseleave = ev => {root.style.backgroundColor='initial'}
```

The code above performes the css :hover metatag.