# CSS hover in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, dom, hover

I create an element like: `var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");`

Then I append it to the DOM like: `document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0].appendChild(btn);`

I want to change the onHover property for the button. I want to achieve something like:

```
btn.style.onHover ="background: #3cb0fd";
```

OR

```
btn.style.backgroundColor.onHover ="#3cb0fd";
```

I am not sure what's the right code for this.

Comment: I'd say use CSS. `button:hover { background: #something; }` or JS events `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave`.

Comment: Here is an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11371599/616535

Comment: use css its more simpler.