# Javascript backgroundColor does remove css hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

My div has class:

```
.cls { background-color: #ff0000; }
.cls:hover { background-color: #0000ff; }
```

When with `javascript` I do:

```
mydiv.style.backgroundColor = "#555555";
```

It works but the hover doesn't work anymore!

I haven't found much information about this behavior on the net, is it normal?

How to fix could be another question but if you want to tell...

Comment: can youm add your html code?

Comment: it's normal - see [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to understand why

Comment: one easy fix is to set `!important` flag on the hover background color

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you are giving **background-color** from javascript so it is applied as inline style and if you want to give hover effect then apply **!important** to it.

```
.cls { background-color: #ff0000; }
.cls:hover { background-color: #0000ff !important; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Very interesting though it is weird behaviour.

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("cls")[0];
elem.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; // It'll become inline property
```

```css
.cls {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.cls:hover { background-color: #0000ff; }
```

```html
<div class="cls"></div>
```

When we are applying `background-color` from Javascript, it'll become inline property and taking high priority over other properties and even overriding `background-color` from `hover`effect.

For a POC, look at this

```css
.cls {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
   background-color: #ff0000; }
.cls:hover { background-color: #0000ff; }
```

```html
<div class="cls" style="background-color: yellow"></div>
```

Now, i'm applying `background-color` from `inline` and here also it is taking high priority over `css` styles.

Solution for this cause is, adding **!important** on `hover`

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("cls")[0];
elem.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```

```css
.cls {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.cls:hover { background-color: #0000ff !important; }
```

```html
<div class="cls"></div>
```

**UPDATE**

As @Mr_Green said, adding `!important` property is not best practice, instead we can add one more class will also solves your problem.

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("cls")[0];
elem.classList.add('secondary');
```

```css
.cls {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.secondary {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.secondary:hover {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="cls"></div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes, it is strange for me because I always thought that pseudo class styles will precede the inline styles. The solution would be not to go with `!important` for pseudo class styles but to add a separate class dynamically which holds the styles.

Comment: @Jackt `classList` is not supported by IE9 and older

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work that
giving class 'cls2' to mydiv in Javascript
and

```
.cls:not(.cls2) { background-color: #ff0000; }
.cls2 { background-color:#555555; }
.cls:hover { background-color: #0000ff; }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe add onmouseenter, onmouseleave event listener to implement the hover.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the background color using javascript will overwrite that element's style.

if you really want to add the hover effect using javascript you can refer to this post: [Change :hover CSS properties with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371550/change-hover-css-properties-with-javascript)

I recommend you to use JQuery for these type of codes.

Answer (score 0):

**check the snippet . its working**

```js
var myDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.cls')[0];
myDiv.style.background='green'
```

```css
.cls{ background-color: #ff0000; height:100px; width:100px; }
.cls:hover { background-color: #0000ff !important; }
```

```html
   

 <div class="cls">
</div>
```