# When mouseover (hover) on object the mouse cursor should change ( three.js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js, hover

I have added a sphere and plane geometry to the scene when clicked on plane geometry it is linked to a website
now when hover on plane geometry the "mouse cursor" should change to "mouse pointer (hand)" and when not hovered 
on plane geometry the mouse should retain its original style. 
I tried using this statement "$('html,body').css('cursor','pointer');" but mouse cursor is not changing on 
hovering, its changing when clicked on plane geometry and its cursor is not retaining to its original position.
can someone please help me how to solve the problem. I have also uploaded the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<script src ="./three.js-master/build/three.js"></script>

<script src ="./three.js-master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js">
</script>
<script src ="./three.js-master/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="math.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">


window.onload = createsphere();
function createsphere() 
{
var controls,scene,camera,renderer;
var planes = [];
var baseVector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
var camDir = new THREE.Vector3();
var planeLookAt = new THREE.Vector3();
function init() 
{

    var spriteResponse = [];
    spriteResponse[0] = {ID:1, x: 0, y: 0};
    spriteResponse[1] = {ID:2, x: 0, y: 0.1};
    spriteResponse[2] = {ID:3, x: 0, y: 0.5};
    spriteResponse[3] = {ID:4, x: 0.5, y: 0};
    spriteResponse[4] = {ID:5, x: 0.25, y: 0.5 };

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    //camera.position.y = 1;
    camera.position.z = 1 ;             
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);      
 /* ------------------------ creating the geometry of sphere------------------------------*/

    var radius = 2.5;
    var spheregeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, 20, 20, 0, -6.283, 1, 1);
    //var texture =  THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture ('rbi00000083.jpg');
    //texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    //var spherematerial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});
    var spherematerial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: '#A9A9A9'});
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(spheregeometry, spherematerial); 
    scene.add(sphere);
    scene.add(camera);
    scene.autoUpdate = true;                
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.minPolarAngle = Math.PI/4;
    controls.maxPolarAngle = 3*Math.PI/4;   

    for(var i=0; i<spriteResponse.length;i++)
    {




        //var spriteAlignment = new THREE.Vector2(0,0) ;
        material_plane = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffffff,side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
        material_plane.needsUpdate = true;
        //material.transparent=true;
        geometry_plane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(0.3, 0.2);
        plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry_plane, material_plane );
        plane.database_id = spriteResponse[i].ID;
        plane.LabelText   = spriteResponse[i].name;




        plane.position.set(spriteResponse[i].x,spriteResponse[i].y,-1);



        scene.add(plane);
        //plane.userData = { keepMe: true };
        planes.push(plane);
        //plane.id = cardinal.ID;
        //var direction = camera.getWorldDirection();
        camera.updateMatrixWorld();
        var vector = camera.position.clone();
        vector.applyMatrix3( camera.matrixWorld );
        plane.lookAt(vector);
        plane.userData = { URL: "http://stackoverflow.com"};
        document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );

    }

    function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) 
    {

        //clearScene();
        event.preventDefault();

        var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
        mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );               
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( planes );                  

        var matched_marker = null;
        if(intersects.length != 0)
        {
            $('html,body').css('cursor','pointer');//mouse cursor change
            for ( var i = 0;  intersects.length > 0 && i < intersects.length; i++)
            {
                window.open(intersects[0].object.userData.URL);
            }
        }
        else
            $('html,body').css('cursor','cursor');//mouse cursor change
    }//onDocumentMouseDown( event )





}
function animate() 
{
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
init();
animate();


}

</script>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do it, but to keep it simple and make it easier for you to understand, my example includes a method that keeps with the format of the code you provided in your question.

I added a `mousemove` event to your `init()` function. The handler looks like this:

```
function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( planes );

    if(intersects.length > 0) {
        $('html,body').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    } else {
        $('html,body').css('cursor', 'default');
    }

}
```

All this does is check whether or not one of your planes is intersected each time you move the mouse.

The reason this wasn't working before is because you only changed the cursor on mouse-down which won't give the desired 'hover' effect.

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BFG/bc01kqcd/35/). Just note that I've commented out any controls related code to get the fiddle working quicker, it won't change the solution.

Comment: without jQuery:
`if (intersects && intersects.length > 0) { document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer' } else { document.body.style.cursor = 'default' }`

Answer (score 1):

You can't change hover state within JS as stated here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11371599/5001964

I think easiest solution would be to make it with css:

```
body:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Although it would be better if instead `body` you choose a specific DOM node to make the hover effect.