# Toopltip only in Javascript (&Not every tooltip on the whole page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I do this(or something alike this) tooltip in only javascript without linking any template styles (I don't want to implement It to all the tooltips on the whole page). I'm designing the webpage on SharePoint which deletes all the ...
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip_top

Answer (score 0):

You can always add inline styles via JS.

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("class-name");
a.forEach(function(e) {
  e.style.property = "value";
});
```

For adding `:hover` effects however, I think you need to append a stylesheet. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11371599/5267919).

Your other option is to use `mouseover` effects, but that is ridiculous when `:hover` exists.

Comment: Well I am kind of new to this, but then do you write?:
<p class="class-name">Hover me<p>

And then when you hover "value" will show?

Comment: It should. Though, you can't easily add hover effects that way. Look at the example link. That is probably easier for your situation.