# Change a stylesheeted CSS value via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey I would like to know how to change a CSS value of the document & not from a specific element

I alredy checked [Change :hover CSS properties with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371550/change-hover-css-properties-with-javascript) but the solution adds CSS rules.
I've read this too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle but targets a specific element too...

I would like to change a value that has been declared in the css file, some kind of an 'absolute value'

It might be something like (we'll here change color of `a` tag) :

```
var sheet = document.getStyle();
sheet.getTagStyle('a').getProperty('color').setValue('rgb(0,0,0)');
```

(The solution must anyway be in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle but I don't get it)

So, is this kind of thing possible, and if yes how?
**(Beware in js not jquery please)**

Comment: I don't think so the provided answer is absolutely not what I want

Comment: You want to know how to change a value in a CSS stylesheet. The third paragraph of the linked accepted answer starts right into how to retrieve the stylesheets and change the values.

Comment: What do you paragraph...

Answer (score 0):

Iterate `document.styleSheets`, check if `.selectorText` of `.cssRules` matches selector, set `.style` of `.cssRules`

```js
for (let {cssRules} of document.styleSheets) {
  let [{selectorText, style}] = cssRules;
  if (selectorText === "a") {
    style.color = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
  }
}
```

```css
a {
  color: rgb(122, 125, 22);
}
```

```html
<a>123</a>
```

Comment: Explain me pls how does work "let" "of"

Comment: @BernieNoël https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: Thx for this man you simplify my life on some parts ;)