# change image on hover with inline code

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to change image on hover. I have tried many ways but nothing is working. And i have to use something like this. Please if there is some problem with this code tell me. Thanks in Advance

**Code**

```
    <a href = "https://my-website.com/results/testimonials-global-supply-chain-group/">
    <img id = "home-button" alt = "" src = "https://my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/businessman-2606509_1920_20171107090703313.jpg" 
     onmouseover="$(this).attr('src','https://my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/testimonialpage.jpg');" 
     onmouseout="$(this).attr('src','https://my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/businessman-2606509_1920_20171107090703313.jpg');">
    </a>
```

Comment: This should work...

Comment: instead of using jqeury, use javascript.

Comment: Have you included jQuery?

Comment: and do you even have images in the path mentioned  ?

Comment: There's no excuse for using inline code; especially when delegated event handlers exist.

Comment: yes #Soolie but it is not working.

Comment: Open your browser's console and see what errors you're getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that you need to do is to check if you have included jQuery and look at the console for errors. Also, you don't need to do much like how you have done in your code. You can just use `this.src`:

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=Hello"
       onmouseover="this.src='//placehold.it/100?text=Over'"
       onmouseout="this.src='//placehold.it/100?text=Hello'"
       alt=""
  />
</a>
```

**Checklist**

1. Check the console.
2. Is jQuery loaded?
3. Is the image path correct?

Comment: let me try this way

Answer (score 1):

Uhh.. so you could use jquery. But you could also just use CSS which is probably much easier. You just use the `:hover` selector and change the `background-image` property on hover [as shown here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/alter-an-image-on-mouse-hover/5415487137857536).
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Alter an image on mouse hover</title>
        <style>
            .image {
                width: 130px;
                height: 195px;
                clip-path: border-box;
                background: url(https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drodd.com%2Fimages14%2Fred4.jpg&f=1&nofb=1) no-repeat;
            }
            .image:hover{
                background: url(https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.zAvnUSUdzPkfFVXmUxbBpQHaE6%26pid%3DApi&f=1) no-repeat;
            }
            body {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                text-align: center;
            }
 
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="image" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We'd prefer if you include your example as code in your answer. Links can go dead meaning the information will be lost and your answer might not be clear enough by itself.

Comment: Sorry, got it now!

Comment: this is not inline 

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work.

Hover effect in `jQuery`  :

```
function hover(element) {
    element.setAttribute('src', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff');
}
function unhover(element) {
    element.setAttribute('src', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff');
}
```

and `HTML` :

`<img src="my-src" onmouseover="hover(this);" onmouseout="unhover(this);" />`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change image on hover, you can use css to do it.

If you want to do it on runtime, can use method in this post. 
[Change :hover CSS properties with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371550/change-hover-css-properties-with-javascript)

Comment: We'd prefer if you include your example as code in your answer. Links can go dead meaning the information will be lost and your answer might not be clear enough by itself.