# change image on hover, but it's not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to change image on hover. But it is some how not working

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".card .image-container").mouseover(function () {
  $(this).attr('src', $(this).data("hover"));
}).mouseout(function () {
  $(this).attr('src', $(this).data("src"));
});
)};
</script>
```

```html
<div class="card col-xs-2" style="margin-top:33%;padding:0 2% 2% 2%">
  <img 
   src="img/2013-1.png" 
   data-src="img/2013-1.png" 
   data-hover="img/2013-2.png" 
   class="image-container" 
   alt="" 
   style="max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%;width: 100%;height: 100%"
   />
```

Comment: can you also post the rest of your relevant js code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182389/change-image-on-hover-with-inline-code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change image on hover with inline code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182389/change-image-on-hover-with-inline-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little mix-up while closing off your function. Hence the syntax error.

Here's the correct code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".card .image-container").mouseover(function () {
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).data("hover"));
        }).mouseout(function () {
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).data("src"));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanku so much man!! i have been trying for so long.... but you made it work!! @crazychukz

Comment: @pawanshaw Glad it worked for you. Could please accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `mouseover` you can use `hover`. Like this:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".card img").hover(function(){
      var hoverImg = $(this).data("hover");
      $(this).attr('src', hoverImg);
      }, function(){
      $(this).attr('src', $(this).data("mysrc"));
  });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card col-xs-2" style="margin-top:15%;padding:0 2% 2% 2%">
  <img src="https://placebear.com/300/300" data-mysrc="https://placebear.com/300/300" data-hover="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="image-container" alt="" style="max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%;width: 100%;height: 100%"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is typo have a look at the closing of your code. It should be `})` instead of `)}`

Answer (score 0):

Separate class names with comma. In jquery multi selector you need to use comma between classes names.

$(".card, .image-container")

Answer (score 0):

try this

I used two google images here, you can replace it with your own

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".card .image-container").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).data('src', $(this).prop("src")).attr('src', $(this).data("hover"));
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data("src"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card col-xs-2" style="margin-top:33%;padding:0 2% 2% 2%">
  <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-5bPNsF5plzw/VnJWs-7RbrI/AAAAAAAARmA/DaZmn8YUjAk/s1600-r/logo_research_at_google_color_1x_web_512dp.png" data-hover="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/839721704163155970/LI_TRk1z_400x400.jpg" class="image-container"
    alt="" />
</div>
```