# how to simulate hover of css using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a below HTML file and when I manually move cursor on the dummy link, it shows me yellow color, as I have added that style on css hover.
Same I would like to simulate with java script.
Here below is the image for reference.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lCeE.png)

Please suggest me how to achieve it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a:hover {
   background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="https://####">dummylink</a>

<p><b>Note:</b> The :hover selector style links on mouse-over.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why using css isn't an option?

Comment: try this link may be it help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371550/change-hover-css-properties-with-javascript

Comment: try this  i hope it will help you
<a href="https://####" onmouseover="style.background='yellow'" onmouseout="style.background='white'" >dummylink</a>

Answer (score 3):

Use the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events:

```js
const a = document.querySelector('a');
a.onmouseover = () => a.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
a.onmouseout = () => a.style.backgroundColor = null;
```

```html
<a href="https://####">dummylink</a>
```

Comment: How do I know the color of element and which style was added for hover.I just want to do the same action which I did manually with javascript i.e  mouse hover.Actually it is for Regression testing in which we automate the actions to test the functionalities.

Comment: If you want to assign the color string to a variable and use it elsewhere, feel free to do so.