# Problem with targetting :hover DOM with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am unable to get the background color of the `li` tags to change to red when my mouse hovers over them.

**excerpt from [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/searching-elements-dom)**

> Can use pseudo-classes as well: Pseudo-classes in the CSS selector like :hover and :active are also supported. For instance, document.querySelectorAll(':hover') will return the collection with elements that the pointer is over now (in nesting order: from the outermost  to the most nested one).

```js
let hover = document.querySelectorAll('li:hover');

for (let elem of hover) {
  elem.style.background = 'red';
};
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: From the site you cited: "document.querySelectorAll(':hover') will return the collection with elements that the pointer is over now". When your JS runs, nothing is being hovered. If you just want the li background to change when you hover over it, forget the JS and just use CSS. `li:hover {background: red}`

Comment: check out this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11371599/4760460).

Comment: Oh. lol im so dumb. Then there's no way for the method to work! I suppose the only way to achieve the result is to addEventListener and mouseenter/mouseover ?

Comment: @Brandon I think that's your best bet. See my answer below.

Comment: @Brandon I'd argue that the best way, objectively, is to do this in CSS. JavaScript should never be used for that which is easily accomplished by CSS. `li:hover { background: red; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off adding a `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event listener to the `li` tags themselves rather than trying to select them based on the `:hover` selector. When the document loads, none of them are being hovered over so the collection is empty.

```js
let hover = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (let elem of hover) {
  elem.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
  })
  elem.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = ''
  })
};
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not calculating that hover event in real-time. I mean, that way you are not subscribing to any event and querySelectorAll is just executed once. To do so you can try for example the event "onmousemove" so every time it fires it will calculate what you need.

This works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
        <li>d</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    window.onmousemove = () => {
      let hover = document.querySelectorAll("li:hover");
      console.log(hover);

      for (let elem of hover) {
        elem.style.background = "red";
      }
    };
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `mouseover` and `mouseout` events for each `li` element.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((v) => {
  v.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    e.target.style.background = 'red';
  });
  v.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
    e.target.style.background = 'white';
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```