# Is it possible to use :hover to change an image?

Tags: html, css

I've designed how my buttons would look in an external app and saved it as an image to use for my webpage, and I want to code the webpage so that when I hover over the button, it changes to the image of the button I've designed - is there a method to do this with html.css?

the current html code:

```
    <div class = 'comment'>
        <a href = "hidden_comments.html">
        <img src='commentbar.jpg', width=90px>
    </div>
```

the css code:

```
.comment{
    display: inline;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. have :hover as selector on the element in css. And add background-image part of css, for example below:

```
div:hover{
  background-image: url("paper.gif");
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's working, is it because in the original code it's set as an image?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use CSS hover to do it. You may want to change image dynamically and you can not do it with CSS.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371550/change-hover-css-properties-with-javascript) you can find an exact solution