# Change :hover::before CSS property with JavaScript var

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, hover, var

Having read through this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371550/change-hover-css-properties-with-javascript) I found that the answer from user ybentz appears to best suite the solution I am looking for as if I do get it working will allow me to greatly reduce my overall JS and CSS.

Basically I have a header with multiple mega-menu items that contain an li.class (sub-menu) with each containing an a.class element. Upon hover::before I am trying to then update the property variable depending upon scroll position. But am getting the following error:

> (index):1591 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setProperty' of
> undefined
>
> at (index):1591
>
> at NodeList.forEach ()
>
> at (index):1591

My code appears as follows;

HTML:

```
<a class="mega-menu-link"></a>
```

CSS:

```
#mega-menu-wrap-primary #mega-menu-primary li.mega-menu-item > ul.mega-sub-menu a.mega-menu-link:hover::before {
    background-color: var(--mega-menu-link-background-color);
}
```

I am then attempting to change the property in an if else based upon the scroll position. I first set my color on page load as scroll is greater than 0. I'll leave all that out as the function works only breaks on the code below.

```
/* var menuSlideColor = document.querySelectorAll('#mega-menu-primary .mega-menu-item > .mega-sub-menu .mega-menu-link'); */

var menuSlideColor = document.querySelectorAll('#mega-menu-wrap-primary #mega-menu-primary li.mega-menu-item > ul.mega-sub-menu a.mega-menu-link:hover::before');
    
menuSlideColor.forEach(function() {
    this.style.setProperty('--mega-menu-link-background-color', 'green');
});

if (currentScrollPos > 0) {
    menuSlideColor.forEach(function() {
        this.style.setProperty('--mega-menu-link-background-color', 'green');
    });
}

else {
    menuSlideColor.forEach(function() {
        this.style.setProperty('--mega-menu-link-background-color', 'white');
    });
}
```

I have tried the following as well.

```
menuSlideColor.forEach((mega-menu-link) => {
    mega-menu-link.style.setProperty('--mega-menu-link-background-color', 'white')
});
```

And

```
menuSlideColor.forEach((mega-menu-link) => {
    mega-menu-link.style.setProperty('--mega-menu-link-background-color', 'green')
});
```

Anything fundamentally wrong with my code?

Comment: So I changed the following and the query selector which cleared  the error but am still not seeing property var being updated.

Comment: Thanks for linking the answer. I'll dig in to that thread and post my final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this link I was able to resolve the issues and have it working as expected.

[David Walsch Answer](http://%20https://davidwalsh.name/css-variables-javascript)

```
:root {
--varMenuHoverColor: value;
--greenColor: #78a300;
--whiteColor: #ffffff;
```

}

```
#mega-menu-wrap-primary #mega-menu-primary li.mega-menu-item > ul.mega-sub-menu a.mega-menu-link:hover::before {
background-color: var(--varMenuHoverColor);
```

}

```
var cssVarGet = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
.getPropertyValue('--varMenuHoverColor');

var greenColor = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
.getPropertyValue('--greenColor');

var whiteColor = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
.getPropertyValue('--whiteColor');

var cssVarSet = function(name, val) {
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(name, val);
};

cssVarSet('--varMenuHoverColor', whiteColor);
```