# How to add hover class for all :hover styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to add `hover` to the `classList` of an element to force trigger hovering styles.

In JS, how can I detect all `:hover` styles and add a `hover` class to have those same styles?

For example, if the class is:

```
a:hover {
}
```

I want to add:

```
a:hover, a.hover {
}
```

I want to write a JS script that makes the conversion I mentioned above, adding the `a.hover` class styles for ALL `:hover`. How can I do this?

NOTE: I don't have access to the CSS. It's loaded in externally so I can't just add to it. This is why I want to make a script that runs on start to do this.

Comment: he be more specific with your question?

Comment: @Aahad thanks for the response. I added my question to the bottom.

Comment: so you want to add a single hover on classes named a?

Comment: @Aahad No, I want to make a class called `hover`, that when applied triggers the hover functionality. But, I want a JS script that does this automatically. So, it goes through the existing styles, and wherever it sees `:hover`, it created a new CLASS called `hover` for that element with the same styles. Does this make sense?

Comment: So you want to apply the same style on every hovered element ?

Comment: Consider using `sass`/`scss`. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend

Comment: @CharlesLavalard No, I want to create a new class for each place that `:hover` occurs. For example, maybe there's `a:hover`. I want to make a class using JS that has the same properties called `a.hover`. Does this make sense?

Comment: Ok so yes as @ulou said consider using sass/scss

Comment: With pure css, you can just create new css class (e.g. `itemHover`) and append it in every html tag you want.

Comment: @ulou So the issue is that I'm not the one writing the CSS, it's loaded in from external. This is why I can't use SCSS and just need to add styles to the existing CSS. Does that make sense? Really appreciate your help!!

Comment: You should've include this information in post description.

Comment: @ulou Ok sorry, still new to this haha. Will add rn.

Comment: @NGI how do you want to distinguish which one should be hovered and which one not?

Comment: @ulou Sorry I'm not sure what you're referring to. Anything with `:hover` in the CSS should add support for using `.hover`. Does that make sense? Thanks again!

Comment: @NGI I'm not sure about this, but I think you cannot do that. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11371599/4983752

Answer (score 0):

As said in comment you could use a sass/scss mixins

SCSS

```
@mixin addHover {
  &.hover {
    background-color: red;
  }
  &:hover {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  @include addHover;
}
```

---

HTML

```
<div class="hover"></div>
<div class=""></div>
<div class=""></div>
<div class=""></div>
<div class=""></div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication, updating my answer, but I actually don't have access to the CSS as it is being loaded in externally. My bad. Really appreciate the help.